# Java: Out with the Old, In with the New

Tags: java

Java is nearing version 7. It occurs to me that there must be plenty of textbooks and training manuals kicking around that teach methods based on older versions of Java, where the methods taught, would have far better solutions now.

What are some boilerplate code situations, especially ones that you see people implement through force of habit, that you find yourself refactoring to utilize the latest versions of Java?

Comment: Why open a bounty on an open ended question? It's not the sort of question you should be chosing an answer on.

Comment: How can someone with a 402 reputation (at this moment) have a question worth 550 bounty?  I know you get 50 from the bounty system, but even after that he would have a -98 reputation.  Or does it take the rep points from you at the time you set the bounty?

Comment: @Bratch - Maybe they had a side job on Wall Street where holding a bounty beyond their purse is the norm.

Comment: @Bratch and Random Echo: The bounty is deducted immediately, not when an answer is accepted. Check his rep history.

Comment: Looking at this list is depressing... I didn't remember Java being that bad, but looking at the new features, as stuff that was missing, I can't believe I used Java... it had no enums, or varargs, or decent generics, or, or, ...

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Enums. Replacing

```
public static final int CLUBS = 0;
public static final int DIAMONDS = 1;
public static final int HEARTS = 2;
public static final int SPADES = 3;
```

with

```
public enum Suit { 
  CLUBS, 
  DIAMONDS, 
  HEARTS, 
  SPADES 
}
```

Comment: the new stuff is much prettier. ;-)

Answer (score 44):

Generics and no longer needing to create an iterator to go through all elements in a collection. The new version is much better, easier to use, and easier to understand.

EDIT:

Before:

```
List l = someList;
Iterator i = l.getIterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    MyObject o = (MyObject)i.next();
}
```

After

```
List<MyObject> l = someList;
for (MyObject o : l) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: The underlying mechanism of the new for loop still creates an iterator, you just don't have to write out the boilerplate code for it.

Comment: I was just about to say that, sk

Comment: yes, but the point is, in your code, you DON'T have to write it, and that is a nice feature of the newer versions of Java. Just because in the background nothing has changed doesn't mean that it isn't a good feature.

Comment: Ah, there's also the fact that generics offer type safety for collections. Refactoring 1.4 code to 1.5 makes a huge difference for readability for this reason, in my mind.

Comment: You mentioned Generics but your loop sample still uses Object. Tsk Tsk. :)

Answer (score 36):

Using local variables of type `StringBuffer` to perform string concatenation. Unless synchronization is required, it is now recommended to use `StringBuilder` instead, because this class offers better performance (presumably because it is unsynchronized).

Comment: ArrayList is preferred to Vector, and HashMap to Hashtable, for the same reason.

Comment: Some modern JITs can tell when a lock is thread-local and optimize it away, making StringBuffer as fast as StringBuilder... but I don't quite recall which JVM(s), exactly, that did this.

Comment: it is called escape analysis - and should be part of jre6

Answer (score 35):

reading a string from standard input:

**Java pre-5**:

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String str = reader.readLine();
    reader.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("error when closing input stream.");
}
```

**Java 5**:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
String str = reader.nextLine();
reader.close();
```

**Java 6**:

```
Console reader = System.console();
String str = reader.readLine();
```

Comment: Unbelievable that it took them so long to make such simple thing really simple to code!

Comment: String string = System.console().readLine(); is even more minimal

Answer (score 24):

Older code using Thread instead of the many other alternatives to Thread... these days, very little of the code I run across still needs to use a raw thread. They would be better served by a level of abstraction, particular [Callable](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html)/[Futures](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)/[Executors](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

See:

[java.util.Timer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

[javax.swing.Timer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html)

[java.util.concurrent.*](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html)

Answer (score 23):

Here is one that I see:

`String.split()` versus `StringTokenizer`.

`StringTokenizer` is not recommended for new code, but I still see people use it.

As for compatibility, Sun makes a huge effort to have Java be backwards and forwards compatible. That partially accounts for why generics are so complex. Deprecation is also supposed to help ease transitions from old to new code.

Comment: :(  Hadn't heard that StringTokenizer was no longer recommended.  I love the StringTokenizer!  Great for decoding switched inputs and complex statements.  Things where it seems like it would be a lot hard to do with split().

Comment: @Brian Knoblauch I think String.split() is supposed to replace the 80% case of using StringTokenizer with a single token and the default flags. You can still use StringTokenizer on more complex situations as you mentioned.

Comment: JavaDoc says "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: @Brian Split and a minimal loop should be close to StringTokenizer, but I agree.  Also I despise regular expressions, which split seems to require.  I also couldn't figure out how to get split to return tokens or not (probably part of the RE syntax I don't want to deal with).

Comment: @Bill: No, they left that out--in other languages, you can return the delimiters by wrapping the regex in parentheses, but not Java. Can't say I blame 'em though, considering how many people don't even realize split _uses_ regexes.

Answer (score 21):

VARARGS can be useful too.

For example, you can use:

```
public int add(int... numbers){
    int sum = 0 ;
    for (int i : numbers){
        sum+=i;
    }
    return sum ;
}
```

instead of:

```
public int add(int n1, int n2, int n3, int n4) ;
```

or

```
public int add(List<Integer> numbers) ;
```

Comment: I've found varargs to be immensely useful.  Hard to imagine what we did before.  There's still lots of legacy APIs out there with overloaded methods with 1 arg, 2 args, 3 args, 4 args, and object[] args. sigh.

Comment: I didn't know that was in java!  was it added in 5 or 6? I haven't done much java aside from academic work and j2me which is 1.4 based :(

Answer (score 16):

Using local variables of type Vector to hold a list of objects. Unless synchronization is required, it is now recommended to use a List implementation such as ArrayList instead, because this class offers better performance (because it is unsynchronized).

Comment: Is this something new? I thought this was always the case.

Comment: Depends on how you define "new".  I'm stuck writing Java 1.1 code (so we can support the people who refuse to upgrade from the MS JVM), and the unsynchronized collections didn't exist back then.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. A Vector is a distinctly different data type from an ArrayList--i.e. look at the setSize method. That said, in most cases a vector type isn't necessary.

Comment: It's a different class (obviously), but they're both implementations of List. My point was that often a Vector is often used where another List implementation could/should be used instead

Comment: Sorry--poorly worded on my part. I complete agree with your point. Just trying to point out that a Vector is a resizable array (like STL) where an ArrayList isn't. In those cases, ArrayList won't work. This catches a lot of C++ converts because they are told ArrayList==Vector.

Comment: java.util.Stack is also the devil.

Answer (score 16):

Formatted printing was introduced as late as in JDK 1.5. So instead of using:

```
String str = "test " + intValue + " test " + doubleValue;
```

or the equivalent using a StringBuilder,

one can use

```
String str = String.format("test %d test %lg", intValue, doubleValue);
```

The latter is much more readable, both from the string concatenation and the string builder versions. Still I find that people adopt this style very slowly. Log4j framework for example, doesn't use this, although I believe it would be greatly benefited to do so.

Comment: I still don't get why they made format a static method. "test %d".format(intValue) would look much nicer!

Comment: Don't see this used much, force of habit, most likely. For more modern logging you can look at logback, which is very nice, and backward compatible with log4j.

Comment: +1 on the log4j - I miss this feature that does exist in log4net.

Comment: Another logging option is Simple Logging Facade for Java (SLF4J), it supports varargs.

Comment: +1. Combined with IntelliJ IDEA's nifty "replace + with String.format() call" intention action, it's now quick & easy to make verbose legacy logging statements a *lot* clearer!

Answer (score 14):

Explicit conversion between primitive and wrapper types (e.g. Integer to int or vice versa) which is taken care of automatically by autoboxing/unboxing since Java 1.5.

An example is

```
Integer myInteger = 6;
int myInt = myInteger.intValue();
```

Can simply be written as

```
Integer myInteger = 6;
int myInt = myInteger;
```

But watch out for NullPointerExceptions :)

Comment: Surely that should be:  

Integer myInteger = new Integer(6);

:)

Comment: No, it's perfectly legal to assign a literal value to an Integer. Your code would work too, but I prefer to use literals for the sake of brevity.

Comment: I think he means that the "before" example should say "new Integer(6)", and the "after" example is already fine.

Comment: Also beware that a boxed int is not equal to a boxed long, even if it has the same value.

Answer (score 11):

Q1: Well, the most obvious situations are in the generics / type specific collections.  The other one that immediately springs to mind is the improved for loop, which I feel is a lot cleaner looking and easier to understand.

Q2: In general, I have been bundling the JVM along side of my application for customer-facing apps.  This allows us to use new language features without having to worry about JVM incompatibility.

If I were not bundling the JRE, I would probably stick to 1.4 for compatibility reasons.

Comment: strive to post one answer at a time (so each can be ranked individually)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...?

Comment: He meant that you should have split this answer into two seperate answers.

Answer (score 11):

A simple change in since 1.5 but makes a small difference - in the Swing API accessing the contentPane of a JFrame:

```
myframe.getContentPane().add(mycomponent);
```

becomes

```
myframe.add(mycomponent);
```

And of course the introduction of Enums has changed the way many applications that used constants in the past behave.

String.format() has greatly improved String manipulation and the ternary if statement is quite helpful in making code easier to read.

Comment: If I recall correctly, myframe.add(...) used to cause a warning message to be printed to stderr.

Comment: Nope, in pre-1.5, the JRE would throw an error at Runtime:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Do not use javax.swing.JFrame.add() use javax.swing.JFrame.getContentPane().add() instead

Answer (score 11):

Generic collections make coding much more bug-resistant.
OLD:

```
Vector stringVector = new Vector();
stringVector.add("hi");
stringVector.add(528); // oops!
stringVector.add(new Whatzit());  // Oh my, could spell trouble later on!
```

NEW:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
stringList.add("hello again");
stringList.add(new Whatzit()); // Won't compile!
```

Answer (score 11):

Using Iterator:

```
List list = getTheList();
Iterator iter = list.iterator()
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  String s = (String) iter.next();
    // .. do something
}
```

Or an alternate form sometimes seen:

```
List list = getTheList();
for (Iterator iter = list.iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
  String s = (String) iter.next();
  // .. do something
}
```

Is now all replaced with:

```
List<String> list = getTheList();
for (String s : list) {
  // .. do something
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Although I admit that static imports can easily be overused, I like to use

```
import static Math.* ;
```

in classes that use a lot of Math functions.  It can really decrease the verbosity of your code.  I wouldn't recommend it for lesser-known libraries, though, since that can lead to confusion.

Comment: +1. Especially useful if you have a bunch of constants defined in one class, and another class heavily uses them. Of course, misusing static imports can easily make code less clear (especially for method calls).

Answer (score 10):

copying an existing array to a new array:

**pre-Java 5**:

```
int[] src = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] dest = new int[src.length];
System.arraycopy(src, 0, dest, 0, src.length);
```

**Java 6**:

```
int[] src = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int[] dest = Arrays.copyOf(src, src.length);
```

formerly, I had to explicitly create a new array and then copy the source elements to the new array (calling a method with a lot of parameters). now, the syntax is cleaner and the new array is returned from a method, I don't have to create it. by the way, the method [Arrays.copyOf](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf(int[],%20int)) has a variation called [Arrays.copyOfRange](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int[],%20int,%20int)), which copies a specific region of the source array (pretty much like [System.arraycopy](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int))).

Comment: Old post, I know, but if you want to make an exact copy of an array then `clone()` is the easiest way (and has been from the birth Java): `int[] copy = original.clone();` The `clone` return type for arrays is covariant (since 1.5), so you don't even need casting. But I agree `Arrays.copyOf` is sweet, sweet sugar for other copy operations.

Answer (score 9):

Converting a number to a String:

```
String s = n + "";
```

In this case I think there has always been a better way of doing this:

```
String s = String.valueOf(n);
```

Comment: String.valueOf(n) takes care of that last problem.

Comment: String s = n + ""; is a bad habit because it will always create a new object.  valueOf is smarter about that.

Comment: You're right, it's too early in the morning I completely forgot about String.valueOf(n).  I've updated it.

Comment: valueOf: since at least version 1.3

Comment: Don't forget the static Integer.toString(int, int) method. This gives you a String representation of the first parameter in the base specified by the second parameter.

Comment: This is one of those things that's so common I wish the compiler would just handle it for you.

Comment: @chriskes it does, just use the s=n+""!  Until someone can actually demonstrate production code where these stupid little tweaks actually speed something up, I'm going to stick with not outsmarting the compiler by trying to understand how it implements these things (which change every release)

Answer (score 8):

The new `for`-each construct to iterate over arrays and collection are the biggest for me.

These days, when ever I see the boilerplate `for` loop to iterate over an array one-by-one using an index variable, it makes me want to scream:

```
// AGGHHH!!!
int[] array = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    // Do something...
}
```

Replacing the above with the [`for` construct introduced in Java 5](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html):

```
// Nice and clean.    
int[] array = new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
for (int n : array)
{
    // Do something...
}
```

Clean, concise, and best of all, it gives *meaning* to the code rather than showing *how* to do something.

Clearly, the code has meaning to iterate over the collection, rather than the old `for` loop saying how to iterate over an array.

Furthermore, as each element is processed independent of other elements, it may allow for future optimizations for parallel processing without having to make changes to the code. (Just speculation, of course.)

Answer (score 6):

Related to [varargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258954/java-out-with-the-old-in-with-the-new/261297#261297); the utility method  [Arrays.asList()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) which, starting from Java 5, takes varargs parameters is immensely useful.

I often find myself simplifying something like

```
List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
items.add("one");
items.add("two");
items.add("three");
handleItems(items);
```

by using

```
handleItems(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three"));
```

Answer (score 6):

Annotations

I wonder no one mentioned it so far, but many frameworks rely on annotations, for example [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) and [Hibernate.](https://www.hibernate.org/) It is common today to deprecate xml configuration files are in favor of annotations in code (though this means losing flexibility in moving from configuration to meta-code, but is often the right choice).The best example is EJB 2 (and older) compared to [EJB 3.0](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/java/newsletter/articles/simplifying_ejb3.html) and how programming EJB has been simplified thanks to annotations.

I find annotations also very useful in combination with some AOP tools like AspectJ or Spring AOP. Such combination can be very powerful.

Answer (score 5):

Changing JUnit 3-style tests:

```
class Test extends TestCase {
    public void testYadaYada() { ... }
}
```

to JUnit 4-style tests:

```
class Test {
   @Test public void yadaYada() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Does that really help anything?

Comment: Yeah, a summary of advantages would be nice. It is not obviously clear from the example why JUnit 4 style would be better.

Comment: @Test(expected=ExpectedException.class)

Comment: Your test case can now extend the class under test to easily test protected methods.

Comment: @Mark: For those using the common idiom of having test class *in the same package* as the code being tested (but under different dir structure), there's nothing new there.

Answer (score 4):

Improved singleton patterns.  Technically these are covered under the popular answer enums, but it's a significant subcategory.

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;

    public void someMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

is cleaner and safer than

```
public class Singleton {
    public static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {
        ...
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Converting classes to use generics, thereby avoiding situations with unnecessary casts.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little wary to refactor along these lines if that is all you are doing to your source tree.  The examples so far do not seem like reasons alone to change any working code base, but maybe if you are adding new functionality you should take advantage of all the new stuff.

**At the end of the day, these example are not really removing boiler plate code**, they are just using the more manageable constructs of newer JDKs to **make nice looking boiler plate code**.

Most ways to make your code elegant are not in the JDK.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, now it's my turn to get yelled at.

I don't recommend 90% of these changes.

It's not that it's not a good idea to use them with new code, but breaking into existing code to change a for loop to a for(:) loop is simply a waste of time and a chance to break something. (IIWDFWI) If it works, don't fix it!

If you are at a real development company, that change now becomes something to code-review, test and possibly debug.

If someone doing this kind of a refactor for no reason caused a problem of ANY sort, I'd give them no end of shit.

On the other hand, if you're in the code and changing stuff on that line anyway, feel free to clean it up.

Also, all the suggestions in the name of "Performance" really need to learn about the laws of optimization.  In two words, Don't!  Ever!  (Google the "Rules of optimization if you don't believe me).

Comment: If it works but is ugly and you don't fix it when you have the time, then chances are that when you need to make changes to the code you will be too busy to do the refactoring, too scared because a tight deadline is looming, and more likely to make errors because you didn't clean it up when you had the chance. The basic idea of refactoring is that it pays off technical debt and makes your life easier in the future.

Comment: What is ugly?  I consider ugly duplicate code, nasty parameter sets on a method, classes that have too much intimate knowledge of each other, etc.  A traditional for loop isn't really difficult or anything, just less concise.  If it's actually fixing one of the "Ugly" items I just mentioned, go for it!  But don't just start adding (or removing) this. in front of every member variable because you think one way or the other is less "Ugly"

Comment: These refactorings shouldn't take any human input whatsoever to be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Using Swing's new `DefaultRowSorter` to sort tables versus rolling your own from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

New version of Java rarely break existing code, so just leave old code alone and focus on how the new feature makes your life easier.

If you just leave old code alone, then writing new code using new features isn't as scary.

Comment: That's fine if your old code is perfectly bug-free, never needing any maintenance!

Comment: All code everyone ever creates is legacy code. What do good boyscouts do to the campsite? :)

Comment: I kind of agree with this. If I'm in a function fixing bugs or adding functionality, I'll refactor it as well. But I'll never refactor something that still works just to utilize new features.

Comment: Most of us probably aren't fortunate enough to be able to 'leave old code alone'. And when you do touch it, it'd be silly not to use the new features (unless, of course, that old code needs to work in 1.4 or something).

Answer (score 1):

String comparisons, really old school Java programmers I've met would do:

```
String s1 = "...", s2 = "...";

if (s1.intern() == s2.intern()) {
    ....
}
```

(Supposedly for performance reasons)

Whereas these days most people just do:

```
String s1 = "...", s2 = "...";

if (s1.equals(s2)) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: intern is a memory thing not a speed thing, indeed intern will make your code slower as it is an expensive operation (unless they have fixed that recently... actually I'll know soon I am about to do something that will test it)

Comment: Also, in this case s1 and s2 are literal strings so they are automatically intern'ed according to the spec.  So the first example is actually a waste of typing.

Comment: From the beginning, the proper way to compare Strings for equality was almost always equals().  What intern() does is take a String and return a reference to a canonical String in a pool maintained by class String. All literals are added to this pool too.  Interned Strings and literals *can* be compared for identity with == at high speed.  In a thorough optimization of a large server, I found two spots where intern() led to measurable performance gains.  In 99.99% of all cases, though, use equals() to prevent bugs and to keep the literal pool smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Using Vector instead of the new Collections.

Using classes instead of enums

```
 public class Enum
  {
      public static final Enum FOO = new Enum();
      public static final Enum BAR = new Enum();
  }
```

Using Thread instead of the new java.util.concurrency package.

[Using marker interfaces instead of annotations](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98061)

Answer (score 0):

It is worth noting that Java 5.0 has been out for five years now and there have only been minor changes since then.  You would have to be working on very old code to be still refactoring it.