# Java ArrayList and HashMap on-the-fly

Tags: java, collections

Can someone please provide an example of creating a Java `ArrayList` and `HashMap` on the fly? So instead of doing an `add()` or `put()`, actually supplying the seed data for the array/hash at the class instantiation?

To provide an example, something similar to PHP for instance:

```
$array = array (3, 1, 2);
$assoc_array = array( 'key' => 'value' );
```

Comment: Are you asking for the syntax on how to do that, or a real world example of why you would want to?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
 {
    add("value1");
    add("value2");
 }
};

Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>() {
 {
    put("key1", "value1");
    put("key2", "value2");
 }
};
```

Comment: These approaches are good. But the contents can be modified after creation. Immutable approachs are sooooo nice!

Comment: this is sometimes dangerous. you will get a reference to the enclosing class since the anonymous inner class maintains a reference to its parent object. this may cause problems with garbage collection and serialisation.

Comment: I do not like double-brace initialization at all. Why create a new (non-static) inner class when a simple initializer will do just as well?

Comment: I've always thought that the double brace approach was nice (esp for GUI construction) - but the comment on the parent object reference is very well made. Proceed with caution here. Might be better to make up a little Map builder class that accepts a vararg of objects (key, value, key value, etc...).

Comment: Is there any performance issues? I mean, you create each time an anonimous class, that extend ArrayList. If you will create arraylist instance, and than add items into it, think it will be more cool for performance. Or this classes appear after compilation?

Comment: If you create it like this then it can't be serialized anymore!

Answer (score 40):

A nice way of doing this is using `List.of()` (since Java 8) and `Map.of()` (since Java 9):

```java
List<String> list = List.of("A", "B", "C");
    
Map<Integer, String> map = Map.of(1, "A",
                                  2, "B",
                                  3, "C");
```

Java 7 and earlier may use [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/):

```
List<String> list = ImmutableList.of("A", "B", "C");

Map<Integer, String> map = ImmutableMap.of(
  1, "A",
  2, "B",
  3, "C");
```

Comment: 500kB is a high price to pay just to do that. If the only thing wanted is to fill the Collection on the fly, the accepted answer is IMHO nicest.

Comment: Another reason to dislike this approach is that it's an immutable list, though I'm guessing (without having read the documentation) that there is a mutable list?

Comment: It's immutable by design! But yes, there are other options too. If it's immutable you can easily share one instance between threads, and therefore between web requests.

500 Kb is a high price to pay. But there are so many other goodies in the Google Collectons, it's worth paying the price.

Comment: @Damien- Fair enough, but nothing's stopping users from writing their own version of this method.

Comment: Map.of is Java 9 feature not 8!

Answer (score 32):

Arrays can be converted to `List`s:

```
List<String> al = Arrays.asList("vote", "for", "me"); //pandering
```

Note that this does *not* return an `ArrayList` but an arbitrary `List` instance (in this case it’s an `Array.ArrayList`)!

Bruno's approach works best and could be considered on the fly for maps. I prefer the other method for lists though (seen above):

```
Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>() {
 {
    put("key1", "value1");
    put("key2", "value2");
 }
};
```

Comment: be warned, Arrays.asList does not return an java.util.ArrayList but a fixed-size java.util.Arrays$ArrayList!

Answer (score 8):

for short lists:

```
    List<String> ab = Arrays.asList("a","b");
```

Comment: not really.. from java.util.Arrays.java:

    public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
 return new ArrayList<T>(a);
    }
so it just returns a pre-initialized ArrayList

Comment: Look further in the source. Arrays has its own internal ArrayList class which doesn't support add() or remove().

Comment: and from the documentation of asList: "Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array."

Answer (score 7):

Use a nice anonymous initializer:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("a");
    add("b");
}};
```

Same goes for a Map:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("a", "a");
    put("b", "b");
}};
```

I find this the most elegant and readable.

Other methods demand creating an array first, then converting it to a List - too expensive in my taste, and less readable.

Answer (score 5):

For lists you can use [Arrays.asList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) like this:

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("one", "two");
List<Integer> intList = Arrays.asList(1, 2);
```

For Maps you could use this:

```
public static <K, V> Map<K, V> mapOf(Object... keyValues) {
    Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();

    K key = null;
    for (int index = 0; index < keyValues.length; index++) {
        if (index % 2 == 0) {
            key = (K)keyValues[index];
        }
        else {
            map.put(key, (V)keyValues[index]);
        }
    }

    return map;
}

Map<Integer, String> map1 = mapOf(1, "value1", 2, "value2");
Map<String, String> map2 = mapOf("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2");
```

Note: in `Java 9` you can use [Map.of](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-)
Note2: `Double Brace Initialization` for creating HashMaps as suggested in other answers has it [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/924326/1183010)

Answer (score 3):

You mean like this?

```
public List<String> buildList(String first, String second)
{
     List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
     ret.add(first);
     ret.add(second);
     return ret;
}

...

List<String> names = buildList("Jon", "Marc");
```

Or are you interested in the `ArrayList` constructor which takes a `Collection<? extends E>`? For example:

```
String[] items = new String[] { "First", "Second", "Third" };
// Here's one way of creating a List...
Collection<String> itemCollection = Arrays.asList(items);
// And here's another
ArrayList<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>(itemCollection);
```

Comment: A slight improvement on Jon's suggestion: works for any number of items:

    public List<String> buildList(String... items) {
        return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));
    }

Comment: (The example code could be simplified a little by making use of varags Arrays.asList(); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/258954/java-out-with-the-old-in-with-the-new/635078#635078)

Comment: I was showing the separate steps to make it obvious how to do things when you'd already got an array.

Comment: Why not use var-args so you can pass any number of items?

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("value1", "value2"));
```

I know many of the answers provided similar solutions, but I think this one is a little more exact and more succinct.
If you have lots of values, you might wanna do this:

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(
    "value1",
    "value2",
    "value3",
    ...
));
```