# Creating a Map within Spring Expressions

Tags: java, spring

I wish to create a map within my spring.xml. The closest I can get is a list of lists

```
<bean id="transformerHelper" class="com.common.TransformerHelper">
    <property name="srcSystemIDList" value="{T(java.util.Arrays).asList({'11','50'},{'41','50'}) }" />
</bean>
```

However I really need these values in a map where I can return 50 when searching the key 11 or 41. I need this metadata defined in Spring as it will be stored away from the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way, I recommend to add another property to your class, a String that will hold all the map values (keys and values), something like you already have:

```
{'11','50'},{'41','50'},{'12','34'}
```

Then, instead of injecting the map, inject the string and in it's setter method (if you are using setter injection) call a small method (created by you) that will parse that string and populate the map,  use `StringTokenizer` or what ever you like.

Comment: Ended up doing something similar to this. As the elements were all numbers I stored them in an array and wrote a method similar to StringTokenizer, to transfer the values into a keyed map.

Answer (score 2):

See section A.2.2.5 of [this doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/xsd-config.html), and note this example:

```
<util:map id="emails">
    <entry key="pechorin" value="pechorin@hero.org"/>
    <entry key="raskolnikov" value="raskolnikov@slums.org"/>
    <entry key="stavrogin" value="stavrogin@gov.org"/>
    <entry key="porfiry" value="porfiry@gov.org"/>
</util:map>
```

Comment: Possible to do it in a one liner otherwise it will mean meta data variable hell

Comment: If you really want to do it in a one-liner without concatenating the XML, you'd likely have to come up with some map-serialisation formatting yourself, and write a class to parse that. I think trying to squeeze such stuff into one-line is going to obfuscate the configuration info

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link: [converting-static-2d-string-array-to-hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702565/converting-static-2d-string-array-to-hashmap) and use init method or implement InitializingBean in your bean class.