# Which Way of List Initialize Is Better

Tags: java

I was wondering, which way of initialization of a list is better?

---

```
public class Main {
    private final List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();

    {
        l.add("a");
        l.add("b");
        l.add("c");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Main {

    private final List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        l.add("a");
        l.add("b");
        l.add("c");        
    }};
}
```

---

Comment: Latter works, but you don't have to use `l.`-prefix in body. Plain `add("a");` is enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the former, since it doesn't create an anonymous class; [check the reasons here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization)

Answer (score 6):

I prefer using static factory methods of the next kind:

```
public final class CollectionUtils {
    private CollectionUtils() {  
    }

    public static <T> List<T> list(T... data) {
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    public static <T> ArrayList<T> newArrayList() {
        return new ArrayList<T>();
    }

    public static <T> ArrayList<T> newArrayList(T... data) {
        return new ArrayList<T>(list(data));
    }
}
```

So, you can use them in your code in the next way:

```
import static CollectionUtils.list;
import static CollectionUtils.newArrayList;

public class Main {
    private final List<String> l1 = list("a", "b", "c");
    private final List<String> l2 = newArrayList("a", "b", "c");
}
```

Thus you get relatively compact way of creating and populating lists and don't need to duplicate generic declarations. Note, that `list` method just creates list view of array. You cannot add elements to it later (or remove). Meanwhile `newArrayList` creates usual `ArrayList` object.

As [Joachim Sauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40342/joachim-sauer) noted, these utility methods (and many other useful things) can be found in [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) library (which is now a part of [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/) project).

Comment: I have to vote this one up, since this is the approach I've used on several projects. However, I think you forgot the static imports in the 'Main' example :)

Comment: IDE usually adds them for me)

Comment: Google Collections does this (and a lot of other things) for you. Those factory methods are in the `Lists` class for example.

Comment: I know, but it contains too much stuff for me. Nevertheless, good point, I add it to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the Google Collections information. Good practice keep evolve over time :)

Comment: Guava (Google Collections) has JAR file of approx. 2MB. When I add it to my project, deployment takes few seconds longer (due to parsing that JAR file each time) and due to glassfish memory leaks/problems with redeploy makes me turn glassfish more often. There is no need to use it if you need only several classes, rather makes your own utility classes. That's what I did and I vote up this answer.

Answer (score 2):

Neither, because none is making the list immutable. I guess you want to make it immutable, when you use `final`. If thats not the case, I apologize for my assumption.

If I am correct in assuming that, you should have a look into `Collections.unmodifiableList()`. And the latter will come handy,

```
private final List<String> l = Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("a");
        add("b");
        add("c");        
}});
```

Otherwise, dfa is correct in suggesting the former.

Another way can be this,

```
private final List<String> l = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList("a", 
                                    "b", "c"));
```

Comment: The second example is final so `l` can be accessed inside the anonymous block I assume. That's misguided because you don't need it and you could just write `add("a")` instead of `l.add("a")` but I assume that's the reason rather than pseudo-immutability.