# Creation of linkedList in java directly if we know the elements

Tags: java

```
  List<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>("String1","String2",...);
```

I want something like above.
Is the above line possible in java...?

Comment: It would have taken you less time to compile and run the code then creating this question.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: He's not asking whether this syntax works. He's asking if there's a simple way like this to instantiate and initialize a LinkedList with a set of known values.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior that is why the Javadocs exist you can very quickly look at the constructor summary.  This question offers zero value.

Comment: @Woot4Moo as you can see, there is an answer to his question.

Comment: Seems a reasonable question to me - he's wanting an all in one way to instantiate a Java Collection.  It's not going to be clear how to do this from the API docs as the answers using Arrays.asList prove.  You can also use Collections.addAll with varargs but that's two lines. Voting to close this is premature IMO.  +1.  And the 4 upvotes seem to agree.

Comment: @Marcelo This is a bad question, the answer is in the JavaDocs and is not providing any value as I stated previously.  SO is not a content farm.  Also, had the OP taken 20-30 seconds and searched the constructor summary for LinkedList in Java he would have found the following `LinkedList(Collection<? extends E> c) 
          Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.`

Comment: @Woot4Moo: The javadocs don't tell you a concise way to create a collection to pass into that constructor. It's a very valid question.

Comment: thanks everyone. I don't understand why some people think in stackoverflow that some questions are bad. I would rather suggest that comment only if you like to answer the question and don't clutter the whole area by writing all rubbish. I would like to thank

Comment: planetjones and Swarrior who really understood my question.

Comment: @Woot4Moo, besides the extremely useless question, if one doesn't know why should use a LinkedList they would be better off without.

Comment: @Saurabh, the intent of the question is quite clear but it's asked in a quite bad way, noneless; actually why do you need a linkedList?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

not directly but

```
List<String> ll = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("String1","String2",...));
```

is what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at **[Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)**. It provides various static utility functions (and much much more), such as

```
Lists.newArrayList("a", "b", "c")
```

and similar for other data structures

Answer (score 2):

An alternative approach using double-braces is shown in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization) earlier StackOverflow page.

Answer (score 1):

No, but something similar:

```
LinkedList<String> linkedList = new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("String1", "String2", "String3", "String4", ...));
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use `Arrays.asList("String1", "String2")` for that purpose.

If you need to add elements to the list afterwards, use

```
List<String> ll = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("String1", "String2"));
```

This will give you a list that can be extended.

Answer (score 0):

No not in the way you gave an example of.

You can pass a Collection however.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Answer (score 0):

I prefers option like this:

```
static final List<Integer> nums = new LinkedList<Integer>() {{
add(1);
add(2);
add(3); }};
```

And no matter what time of list.