# What is the shortest way to initialize List of strings in java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, initialization

I am searching for the shortest way (in code) to initialize list of strings and array of strings, i.e. list/array containing 
"s1", "s2", "s3" string elements.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

There are various options. Personally I like using [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
List<String> strings = Lists.newArrayList("s1", "s2", "s3");
```

(Guava's a library worth having anyway, of course :)

Using just the JDK, you could use:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3");
```

Note that this will return an `ArrayList`, but that's *not* the normal `java.util.ArrayList` - it's an internal one which is mutable but fixed-size.

Personally I prefer the Guava version as it makes it clear what's going on (the list implementation which will be returned). It's also *still* clear what's going on if you statically import the method:

```
// import static com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList;
List<String> strings = newArrayList("s1", "s2", "s3");
```

... whereas if you statically import `asList` it looks a little odder.

Another Guava option, if you don't want a modifiable-in-any-way list:

```
ImmutableList<String> strings = ImmutableList.of("s1", "s2", "s3");
```

I typically want to *either* have a completely mutable list (in which case `Lists.newArrayList` is best) *or* a completely immutable list (in which case `ImmutableList.of` is best). It's rare that I really *want* a mutable-but-fixed-size list.

Comment: why not just Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3")?

Comment: @BegemoT: I was adding that - personally I prefer the explicit nature of the Guava version.

Comment: *which is unmodifiable* -- It's actually modifiable (but fixed-sized).

Comment: @Matt: No problem. I'll delete the one replying to you, and then delete *this* one soon, if you want to delete your second one too :)

Comment: With all respect to Jon Skeet. Isn't it better to use Arrays.asList() instead of ImmutableList.of(), as the later, will maintain the copied array. Can you please share some light on this?

Comment: @AshishLohia: Not if you want the list to be immutable. That's why I give multiple options - the best approach depends on what you want the result to be.

Comment: I completely agree with you @JonSkeet . Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 40):

### Java 9+

Java 9 introduces a convenience method [`List.of`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E-E-E-) used as follows:

```
List<String> l = List.of("s1", "s2", "s3");
```

### Java 8 and older

Here are a few alternatives:

```
// Short, but the resulting list is fixed size.
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3");

// Similar to above, but the resulting list can grow.
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3"));

// Using initialization block. Useful if you need to "compute" the strings.
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<String>() {{
    add("s1");
    add("s2");
    add("s3");
}};
```

When it comes to arrays, you could initialize it at the point of declaration like this:

```
String[] arr = { "s1", "s2", "s3" };
```

If you need to reinitialize it or create it without storing it in a variable, you do

```
new String[] { "s1", "s2", "s3" }
```

If the string constants are may though, it would look like

```
String[] arr = { "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8", "s9", "s10",
                 "s11", "s12", "s13" };
```

In these cases I usually prefer writing

```
String[] arr = "s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7,s8,s9,s10,s11,s12,s13".split(",");
```

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: The result of Arrays.asList is immutable. If a new ArrayList is constructed as in `str2` then it is possible to add to the list afterwards.

Comment: @Mathias Schwarz, not immutable, fixed sized.

Comment: @aioobe: You are right! It is possible to overwrite existing entries.

Comment: You should note that the **initialization block** variant creates an anonymous subclass of the ArrayList class.

Comment: pls mention List.of() is also immutable!

Answer (score 15):

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3");
```

All these objects exists in the JDK.

**PS:** As [aioobe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/276052/aioobe) stated, this makes the list fixed-sized.

Comment: The resulting list is fix-sized though.

Answer (score 4):

**JDK2**

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");
```

**JDK7**

```
//diamond operator
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("one");
list.add("two");
list.add("three");
```

**JDK8**

```
List<String> list = Stream.of("one", "two", "three").collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**JDK9**

```
List<String> list = List.of("one", "two", "three");
```

Plus there are lots of other ways supplied by other libraries like Guava.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Arrays` class in the standard Java API: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3");
```

Be aware that the resultning list is fixed-size (you cannot add to it).

Answer (score 3):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), you can write the following:

```
List<String> list = Lists.mutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");
```

You can also be more specific about the types and whether they are Mutable or Immutable.

```
MutableList<String> mList = Lists.mutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");
ImmutableList<String> iList = Lists.immutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");
```

You can also do the same with `Sets`, `Bags` and `Maps`:

```
Set<String> set = Sets.mutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");
MutableSet<String> mSet = Sets.mutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");
ImmutableSet<String> iSet = Sets.immutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");

Bag<String> bag = Bags.mutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");
MutableBag<String> mBag = Bags.mutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");
ImmutableBag<String> iBag = Bags.immutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");

Map<String, String> map = 
    Maps.mutable.with("s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3");
MutableMap<String, String> mMap = 
    Maps.mutable.with("s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3");
ImmutableMap<String, String> iMap = 
    Maps.immutable.with("s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s3", "s3");
```

There are factories for `SortedSets`, `SortedBags` and `SortedMaps` as well.

```
SortedSet<String> sortedSet = SortedSets.mutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");
MutableSortedSet<String> mSortedSet = SortedSets.mutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");
ImmutableSortedSet<String> iSortedSet = SortedSets.immutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");

SortedBag<String> sortedBag = SortedBags.mutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");
MutableSortedBag<String> mSortedBag = SortedBags.mutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");
ImmutableSortedBag<String> iSortedBag = SortedBags.immutable.with("s1", "s2", "s3");

SortedMap<String, String> sortedMap =
        SortedMaps.mutable.with("s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s3","s3");
MutableSortedMap<String, String> mSortedMap =
        SortedMaps.mutable.with("s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s3","s3");
ImmutableSortedMap<String, String> iSortedMap =
        SortedMaps.immutable.with("s1", "s1", "s2", "s2", "s3","s3");
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Guava, but almost all solutions mentioned in other answers and using the JDK suffer have some flaws:

1. The `Arrays.asList` method returns a fixed-size list.
2. {{Double-brace initialization}} is known to create classpath clutter and [slow down execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization). It also requires one line of code per element.
3. **Java 9**: the static factory method [`List.of`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of--)returns a structurally immutable list. Moreover, `List.of` is [value-based](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/doc-files/ValueBased.html), and therefore its contract does not guarantee that it will return a new object each time.

---

Here is a Java 8 one-liner for gathering multiple individual objects into  an `ArrayList`, or any collection for that matter.

```
List<String> list = Stream.of("s1", "s2", "s3").collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

**Note**: aioobe's solution of copying a transitory collection (`new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3"))`) is also excellent.