# The shortest way to fill the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the shortest way to fill the ArrayList?
Something like:

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
list.add({1,10,1,1});
list.add({2,11,1,1});
```

Or:

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> list = ({1,10,1,1},{2,11,1,1});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "shortest"? Least lines of code? For what purpose?

Comment: You can't realistically 'fill' an ArrayList anyway - that's kind of the point of an ArrayList

Comment: yeas, least lines of code. well, elegance + clearness

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520382/what-is-the-shortest-way-to-initialize-list-of-strings-in-java check this

Comment: I wouldn't use `Integer` unless you want `null` values.  It can be more efficient and clearer to use `int`. You can have a `List<int[]>` as `int[]` is an Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix your first attempt:

```
ArrayList<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
list.add(new Integer[]{1,10,1,1});
list.add(new Integer[]{2,11,1,1});
```

Answer (score 16):

How about this shortcut:

```
List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList( new int[][]{{1,10,1,1}, {2,11,1,1}} );
```

Answer (score 6):

Using [guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)

```
Lists.newArrayList(new int[]{1,2,3}, new int[]{2,4,5}, new int[]{5,6,7});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Integer[]> list = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
list.add(new Integer[] { 1, 10, 1, 1 });
list.add(new Integer[] { 2, 11, 1, 1 });
```

Or here is a one-liner:

```
List<Integer[]> list = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 1, 10, 1, 1 }, new Integer[] { 2, 11, 1, 1 });
```