# How can I instantiate a list directly as an actual parameter?

Tags: java, arrays, list, integer, shortcut

I created an list of lists,

```
List<List<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
list.add({1});
list.add({1,1});
```

This is not working.
Is there any shortcut of instantiating them and then adding them?

Thank you.

Comment: [`List.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) is one way, for immutable lists; `Arrays.asList(..)` - is another.

Comment: or earlier `Arrays.asList()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the shortest way to initialize List of strings in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520382/what-is-the-shortest-way-to-initialize-list-of-strings-in-java)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005073/initialization-of-an-arraylist-in-one-line

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 5, you [can](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) initialize your list inline as:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5);
```

---

Since Java 8, you [can](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-) use Stream API as:

```
List<Integer> list = Stream.of(1,2,3,4,5).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

Since Java 9, you [can](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E...-) create immutable lists as:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,3,4,5);
```

---

Finally, you can also use *double brace initializer block*, as:

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>() {
        {
            add(1);
            add(2);
            add(3);
            add(4);
            add(5);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java-9 **`List.of`**.

More about [**`List.of`**](https://javatutorial.net/java-9-immutable-list-example) , you will able to get it from here.

```
List<List<Integer>> list = List.of(List.of(1),List.of(1,1),List.of(1,2,3));
    System.out.println(list);
```