# C# to Java - Dictionaries?

Tags: c#, java, dictionary, new-operator

Is it possible in Java to make a Dictionary with the items already declared inside it? Just like the below C# code:

```
   Dictionary<string, int> d = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"cat", 2},
        {"dog", 1},
        {"llama", 0},
        {"iguana", -1}
    };
```

How do I do this and what type do I use? I've read that Dictionary is obsolete.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{
    put("cat", 2);
    put("dog", 1);
    put("llama", 0);
    put("iguana", -1);
}};
```

This statement creates an anonymous subclass of HashMap, where the only difference from the parent class is that the 4 entries are added during instance creation. It's a fairly common idiom in the Java world (although some find it controversial because it creates a new class definition).

Because of this controversy, as of Java 9 there is a new idiom for conveniently constructing maps: the family of static [Map.of methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-).

With Java 9 or higher you can create the map you need as follows:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Map.of(
    "cat", 2,
    "dog", 1,
    "llama", 0,
    "iguana", -1
);
```

With larger maps, this [alternative syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries-java.util.Map.Entry...-) may be less error-prone:

```
Map<String, Integer> map = Map.ofEntries(
    Map.entry("cat", 2),
    Map.entry("dog", 1),
    Map.entry("llama", 0),
    Map.entry("iguana", -1)
);
```

(This is especially nice if Map.entry is statically imported instead of being referenced explicitly).

Besides only working with Java 9+, these new approaches are not quite equivalent to the previous one:

- They don't allow you to specify what Map implementation is used
- They only create immutable maps
- They don't create an anonymous subclass of Map

However, these differences shouldn't matter for many use cases, making this a good default approach for newer versions of Java.

Comment: And here is an explanation on what this is doing. http://techpolesen.blogspot.com/2007/08/java-initializers-add-elements-to.html

Comment: Hmmm... double braces syntax is not generally considered good style

Comment: @Luigi You're right, I'll change my answer (won't do anything though :P)

Comment: The extra braces are not a style-thing.  They are both functional and necessary to denote the code as an initializer block.

Comment: @Affe - you are aware we are creating a new anonymous class for each such initialization? And what will happen if you try to serialize anything in the map? And the performance impact? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization) Even the writer of the article linked to above says he wouldn't use it in production code.

Comment: I was talking to fireshadow, who thought you meant "use one brace, not two" not "don't anonymously subclass JavaSE library classes just to save yourself a bit of typing."

Comment: @Josh Smeaton: Nice article, although there is a tiny mistake in it: the inner braces are an instance initializer, not a static initializer.

Answer (score 12):

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>(){{
put("cat", 2);
put("dog", 1);
put("llama", 0);
put("iguana", -1);
}};
```

Comment: This doesn't compile, your answer was correct before you edited it.

Answer (score 5):

Bite the bullet and type out the map name!

```
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("cat", 2);
    map.put("dog", 1);
    map.put("llama", 0);
    map.put("iguana", -1);
```

You could also do something like this, which might save some typing with a long list:

```
    Object[][] values = {
        {"cat", 2},
        {"dog", 1},
        {"llama", 0},
        {"iguana", -1}
    };

    for (Object[] o : values) {
        map.put((String) o[0], (Integer) o[1]);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [Guava library](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/), you can use its `ImmutableMap` class, either by itself (examples 1 and 2), or as an initializer for a HashMap (examples 3 and 4):

```
Map<String, Integer> map1 = ImmutableMap.<String, Integer> builder()
    .put("cat", 2)
    .put("dog", 1)
    .put("llama", 0)
    .put("iguana", -1)
    .build();
Map<String, Integer> map2 = ImmutableMap.of(
    "cat", 2,
    "dog", 1,
    "llama", 0,
    "iguana", -1
);
Map<String, Integer> map3 = Maps.newHashMap(
    ImmutableMap.<String, Integer> builder()
    .put("cat", 2)
    .put("dog", 1)
    .put("llama", 0)
    .put("iguana", -1)
    .build()
);
Map<String, Integer> map4 = Maps.newHashMap( ImmutableMap.of(
    "cat", 2,
    "dog", 1,
    "llama", 0,
    "iguana", -1)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Java7 almost introduced "collection literals" that would allow syntax like that. They'll probably try to shove it in Java8. I have no idea what is wrong with these people.

This can be easily achieved by some kind of wrapper API

```
Map<String,Integer> map = Maps.<String,Integer>empty()
    .put("cat", 2).put("dog",1)....;
```

Not too bad. I would prefer something like

```
map("cat", "dog", ... )
.to(  1,     2,   ... );
```

This kind of thing must have been implemented by various people, unfortunately the standard API doesn't inculde such things.