# Creating prepopulated set in Java

Tags: java, initialization, set, declaration

In Java, how do I create a final Set that's populated at construction? I want to do something like the following:

```
static final Set<Integer> NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS 
    = new HashSet<Integer>([1,2,3,6]);
```

but I don't know the proper syntax in Java.

Comment: I nominate this for reopening because there is the subtle difference: this asks specifically for final whereas the other for the general paradigm.  For example, an answer that includes `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` would be proper for this but not the other.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this idiom:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 6))
```

Answer (score 23):

You might consider using Guava's [`ImmutableSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html):

```
static final Set<Integer> NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS = ImmutableSet.<Integer>builder()
        .add(1)
        .add(2)
        .add(3)
        .add(6)
        .build();
static final Set<String> FOO = ImmutableSet.of("foo", "bar", "baz");
```

Among other things, this is significantly faster (and ~3 times more space-efficient) than `HashSet`.

Comment: @Louis - Thanks, I forgot about that simplified syntax.

Answer (score 10):

Using [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library you can use [`ImmutableSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html), which is designed exactly to this case (constant values):

```
static final ImmutableSet<Integer> NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS =
        ImmutableSet.of(1,2,3,6);
```

Old-school way (without any library):

```
static final Set<Integer> NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS =
        new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,6));
```

---

**EDIT:**

**In Java 9+** you can use [*Immutable Set Static Factory Methods*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#immutable):

```
static final Set<Integer> NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS =
        Set.of(1,2,3,6);
```

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way, using standard Java classes, is

```
static final Set<Integer> NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS = 
    Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 6)));
```

But you can also use a static initializer, or delegate to a private static method:

```
static final Set<Integer> NECESSARY_PERMISSIONS = createNecessaryPermissions();
```

Note the `unmodifiableSet` wrapper, which guarantees that your constant set is indeed constant.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this in the following way which IMO is much better and more concise than other examples in this topic:

```
public static <T> Set<T> set(T... ts) {
    return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(ts));
}
```

after importing it statically you can write something like this:

```
public static final Set<Integer> INTS = set(1, 2, 3);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>() {{  
  add("1"); add("2"); add("5");  
}};
```

Comment: Be aware of [double brace initialization drawbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization).