# Java creating objects as arguments to functions

Tags: java, object

Since, I get used to code in javascript, I want to create objects with properties.

Here is my code:

```
jPanel2.add( new JPanel(){ this.add(new JButton("Add")); });
```

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: `jPanel2.add( new JPanel("Text"));`

Comment: i want to add a JPanel, which has a button, inside jPanel2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always use this syntax:

```
container.add(new JPanel() {{ this.add(new JButton("Add")); }});
```

---

Full example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

    frame.add(new JPanel() {{ this.add(new JButton("Add")); }});

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Just a warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization

Comment: Field initializer in anonymous class body?? Genius!!

Comment: @DavidB I wouldn't say that it's unreadable, sometimes it's really neat! :)