# How do I use collection literals in Java 7?

Tags: java, collections

I've tried the following line:

```
Map<Character, Color> map={new Character('r'):Color.red,new Character('b'):Color.black};
```

But Netbeans 7 rejects this, with the error message `'{' expected, ';' expected`.

I've set the Source/Binary format as 'JDK 7'and the platform to 'JDK 1.7', is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: In Java 8, you can use this trick to get reasonable map literals out of lambda expressions: https://gist.github.com/galdosd/10823529

Comment: That trick depends on the compiler in use. I think it works with Eclipse but not with javac.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Neither Java 7 nor Java 8 supports collection literals, as discussed in this question: [Are Project Coin's collection enhancements going to be in JDK8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692213/are-project-coins-collection-enhancements-going-to-be-in-jdk8)

You can use Google's [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library if you need only immutable collections. [`ImmutableList`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableList.html), [`ImmutableSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html) and [`ImmutableMap`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) have several overloaded factory methods or even builders that make creating collections easy:

```
List<Integer> list = ImmutableList.of(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21);
Set<String> set = ImmutableSet.of("foo", "bar", "baz", "batman");
Map<Integer, String> map = ImmutableMap.of(1, "one", 2, "two", 3, "three");
```

**EDIT**

Java 9 has added [collection factory methods](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269) similar to those of Guava:

```
List.of(a, b, c);
Set.of(d, e, f, g);
Map.of(k1, v1, k2, v2)

Map.ofEntries(
    entry(k1, v1),
    entry(k2, v2),
    entry(k3, v3),
    // ...
    entry(kn, vn)
);
```

Comment: Oh, I should've looked it up. It's a shame, really; I was looking forward to using collection literals. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

You need to define a concrete map implementation, optionally combined with double brace initialization:

```
Map<Character, Color> map = new HashMap<Character, Color>() {{ 
  put(new Character('r'), Color.red);
  put(new Character('b'), Color.black );
}};
```

Comment: Hmm, if someone rates a post down, it would be nice to get some feedback why. We're all here to learn, aren't we?

Comment: I personally didn't vote you down, but I see two problems with your code. First, creating an anonymous subclass just for initialization is not a very good practice. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/924536/581205 Second, you don't have to manually create a new Character instance, autoboxing does that for you: `put('r', Color.red);`

Comment: @Natix yes, the double brace initialization is not really recommended I just mentioned it as an answer to the OP's question. It's true that there are far better alternatives to achieve that. Besides that, creating a `Character` manually (manual boxing) or using autoboxing is not really a reason for a downrate. It's a matter of style and I tried to use as much of the OP's code as possible in order to keep confusion low.

Comment: Should use valueOf on all the native classes, though.

Comment: I like this one. I have seen a similar construct elsewhere lately, but there people suggested to never ever use anonymous subclassing to write down literals. I disagree.

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little on Thomas's answer... Map is an interface, and must be instantiated through one of the associated concrete implementations (HashMap, TreeMap, or LinkedHashMap).  It is still good practice; however, to declare your reference variable as the interface implementation rather than the specific concrete, as it provides future flexibility.

Regarding the code snippet though, I think you do still need the Key-value pairs defined in the assignment side of the declaration.  So, I would change:

```
Map<Character, Color> map = new HashMap<>() {{
```

to

```
Map<Character, Color> map = new HashMap<Character, Color>() {{
```

Comment: No, <> operator was added in Java 1.7 as syntactic sugar so you don't need to be so verbose.

Comment: @lmsurprenant you can't use <> with anonymous inner classes