# Are Project Coin's collection enhancements going to be in JDK8?

Tags: java, java-7, jsr, java-8

Initially [Project Coin](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/coin/) had [enhanced support for collections](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2009-March/001108.html) e.g. `list[3]` instead of `list.get(3)` and `map["hello"] = 27` instead of `map.put("hello", 27)` but they were [not in jdk7](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/project_coin_javaone_2010). Are they going to be in jdk8? I could not find a definitive answer for either yes or no.

Comment: AFAIK Project Coin only applied to Java 7. It might apply to Java 8 but I haven't heard anything. Last time they only took the simplest changes to implement.  Given adding closures and virtual extensions etc. are likely to be big tasks, I suspect they won't have the resources.

Comment: Is there a roadmap somewhere I can see what features are in what state and which versions they go into?

Comment: The [List of JDK 8 Features](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/features) does not include these.

Comment: Also, in the project Coin mailing list Joe Darcy [answered this question already](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/coin-dev/2012-February/003454.html). There he explians why these will not be included.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Brian Goetz briefly mentions list, set, map (and other possible) literals in this post in the Project Lambda mailing list from 30th May:

http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-May/004979.html

> To illustrate what I mean by "we could do better", here's an alternative 
>   proposal that gets far more mileage out of #: structured literals. 
>   While these plans are not in place for 8, we have already stated our 
>   desire to add structured literals for lists, maps, sets, etc.  # as a 
>   prefix symbol, combined with delimiters, gives us a far higher 
>   return-on-syntax as a structured literal builder (as a bonus, # is 
>   already associated with structured literals in a lot of languages, going 
>   all the way back to many early assembly languages where # was the 
>   immediate addressing mode.)

So to me it seems that even the collection literals won't make it into JDK 8, let alone the get/set/put operators. It's a pity.

Also I do not see anything relating to collection literals or new operators in the list of JDK 8 milestones:

http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/milestones

Comment: Do you know if its going to be in JDK9?

Comment: Even GOD wont know that :)