# Java - new ArrayList(List) vs empty ArrayList() + add(element)

Tags: java, arraylist

I've learned today that you can create a new ArrayList object utilizing a static method like so:

```
List<String> listDummy = Arrays.asList("Coding", "is", "fun"); 
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(listDummy);
```

Or even more concisely:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Coding", "is", "fun"));
```

**My question is:** How expensive is this performance-wise compared to the "traditional" way? (below)

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add("Coding");
stringList.add("is");
stringList.add("fun");
```

I realize the upper way of creating an ArrayList includes an extra List object creation, however, I prefer the shorter and more compact syntax to an extent that I'm willing to sacrifice **some** performance but gotta draw the line somewhere.

PS. leaving the type information(<>) empty in "new ArrayList<>()" is a Java SE 7 feature, not an error.

Thank you beforehand for any answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual `add()` way calls three methods.

The `asList()` way makes an array, then does `clone()` on it (which does a shallow copy), then does copy all the elements manually because of [this bug](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6260652). And afterwards, if you want to add another element to `stringList`, the array will have to be made larger and elements re-copied, because the size was exact for the elements provided. <sub>(all this is implementation dependant and assumes Oracle JDK)</sub>

For three elements, the latter will be slower, but for any practical use, it will be negligible. For many elements, the two approaches might get equal in performance and the former one *might* even get slower.

Write what you think will read the best, the performance penalty is minimal and you should not care about it until it proves itself to be bottleneck.

---

All that said, if you're after consice syntax, you could like Google Guava's [`Lists`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList%28E...%29):

```
List<String> stringList = Lists.newArrayList("Coding", "is", "fun");
```

I haven't used a classic `ArrayList` constructor for quite a while now.

Comment: Accepting this one. @Peter Lawrey had similar answer right off the bat, but this one goes a bit deeper. Thank you all for your insights!

Answer (score 5):

The performance difference is likely to be 30 - 300 ns depending on your system and how warmed up your code is.  I suspect the performance difference is small.

I always say, if in doubt; write the code as simpler and clear as you can and it will often perform ok as well.

Comment: Totally agree to the simplicity argument. Make it as simple and readable as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line without creating additional lists:

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>(){{
    add("Coding");
    add("is");
    add("fun");
}};
```

This is an anonymous class, which is a *subclass* of ArrayList, with an instance block.

Comment: +1 – Wow, that's some nice and creative abuse of Java syntax! :)

Comment: but anonymous inner classes are rather slow, and its not *really* 1 line. I used to like double brace initialization, but everyone else seems to dislike them.

Comment: @Dariusz: He's making an anonymous class (a class without its own name) that extends `ArrayList`. This class has an instance block in it, that's a piece of code that runs whenever a new instance of the class is created.

Comment: @nim why do you say they are slow? Do you have evidence of slowness?

Comment: Well you create an anonymous class with an anonymous initializer. A lot of work for simply initializing a list plus it's not exactly concise. I would stick to Arrays.asList...

Comment: @Bohemian yes, give me a min - well there is a benchmark on stackoverflow. They are very much slower. I used to use this style all over the place, then i read lots of answers where people didn't like it, and then I found the performance benchmark. I realized its really not any better than just doing stringlist.add() without the double brace initialization - it just looks *tricky*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization

Comment: @NimChimpsky: That benchmark only proves that loading 1000 classes takes longer than loading 1 class...

Comment: @jlordo doesn't really matter why it is slower. Only that it is.

Comment: Ok, I don't want to have the same discussion here as in the other thread. If you benchmark a warmed up system, there will be no difference. Let's settle this with: the best solution is to use the most readable code.

Comment: @NimChimpsky: As I see it, it shows 10 **individual runs** of each `Test` class, so there is no warmup phase before he takes the time...

Comment: @NimChimpsky: yes, but if you take the code of that benchmark and put it in a loop, you'll get the high number for the first run of the loop, and `0` for all other runs. So, the benchmark proves that having 1000 anonymous classes is more expensive than having none, but there will be no performance difference at all once all of them are loaded (ergo, no difference after the warmup. When talking about efficiency of a car, I consider how many gallons it uses per mile, and don't care how much it uses to start the motor)

Comment: @jlordo yeah OK, maybe they are not so bad afterall.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not going to add /remove elements from the list after creation then the best way is not to create ArrayList at all, this will be really efficient

```
List<String> listDummy = Arrays.asList("Coding", "is", "fun");
```

otherwise `new ArrayList<>(listDummy)` is more efficient than manual adding elements one by one, see ArrayList(Collection) src:

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    elementData = c.toArray();
    size = elementData.length;
    // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
    if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
}
```

it's optimized:

1) it creates the array of exact size
2) it uses native copying of elements

Answer (score 1):

The list you get from Arrays.asList is already an ArrayList, so it is not necessary to wrap it with an ArrayList again:

```
  public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(a);
    }
```

Caveat: The list is read-only, so if you need to write it, you will need to wrap it indeed using new ArrayList(..).

Nevertheless, I think using Arrays.asList should be better than creating a list using repeated calls of "add", because the ArrayList's internal array is initialized with the correct size. So the best way would be

```
List<String> myList= Arrays.asList("Coding", "is", "fun");
// or if you need to write the list
List<String> myList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("Coding", "is", "fun"));
```

Also this is the most readable IMHO, and readability for me always wins over very small performance gains unless you really need that extra performance. If you really need to do performance tuning, use a profiler. The bottleneck is usually where you wouldn't expect it to be. A profiler can give you exact information about what parts of your program are slow and you can optimize them as needed.

Comment: No. It has the same name, but is _not_ the same! You can't add to it.

Comment: Bummer. Indeed you're right. Well I'd still use Arrays.asList and maybe wrap it if you need to write to the list.

Answer (score 0):

**The performance difference depends on size of the source array.**

If you are adding items one by one multiple reallocations inside destination array will happen.

If you are adding whole collection at once only one allocation should be done, because the size is known beforehand.

Comment: Although in the examples above only neither example resizes.

Comment: @PeterLawrey How do you know? Can you really assume what is the default allocation size of internal structure of ArrayList on every JVM implementation?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe the default initial capacity would be less than 3, on a JVM the OP is likely to be using?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Do you think that the person, who asked question wants to add at most 3 items to array?

Comment: You say "multiple reallocations inside destination array **will** happen" when it is not clear that is the case from the example given.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use a convenience function:

```
public static <T> ArrayList<T> asArrayList(T... args) {
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>(args.length);
    Collections.addAll(list, args);
    return list;
}
```

This is a bit quicker than the `Arrays.asList` route. (Not that it would ever really matter for hard-coded lists.)