# Does using braces inside a Java method reduce performance?

Tags: java, performance, block

It seems as though [double-brace initialization increases overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization).

Does using braces inside of a method also reduce performance?

eg.

```
public class DoIReducePerformanceToo {

    public void aMethod() {

        {
           // Is it a bad idea to use these?
        }

    }

}
```

I've taken a look at Java's [grammar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html) and it seems that this is classified as a block:

```
Block: 
    { BlockStatements }

BlockStatements: 
    { BlockStatement }

BlockStatement:
    LocalVariableDeclarationStatement
    ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration
    [Identifier :] Statement
```

but I'm not sure where in the grammar double-brace initialization falls.

My question: does using block statements in methods reduce performance in Java? And are these blocks of the same nature as double-brace initialization?

EDIT:

Inner class instantation is:

```
ClassCreatorRest: Arguments [ClassBody]

ClassBody: 
    { { ClassBodyDeclaration } }
```

Comment: It's not syntactically the braces that affect performance but what that means. In that situation it means create a new class and instantiate it. In this situation, it doesn't mean anything and it will be removed as dead code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The double-brace initialization trick has *nothing* to do with normal scopes.

Instead, it creates an anonymous class that inherits the type your initializing, and runs your code in an initialization block (which is syntactic sugar for a constructor).

This extra class has overhead.

Comment: Thanks! Would you be able to point me to the location in the grammar where double-brace initialization is defined?

Comment: @sdasdadas: `ClassCreatorRest: 
    Arguments [ClassBody]`

Comment: It isn't, really; the double-brace initialization technique is just a normal initializer block inside a normal anonymous class.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I found the regular class declaration but couldn't quite find the inner class declaration. :)

Comment: @SLaks this isn't answering the OP's question, is it? I thought it was about a block statement, not about inline initializer blocks...

Comment: @feralin You answered why a block statement is the same speed as no block statement (which answers the question too). I was mainly concerned, however, that block statements were somehow tied to instantiating a class (which, in retrospect, seems silly).

Answer (score 3):

The block syntax is a part of the grammar, but also changes things such as variable scope. However, after compilation, variables, syntax, scope, and all is just converted into a plain bytecode format. The bytecode does not care about scoping rules, and the like, so there should be **no overhead** to using extra blocks in your code.

For example, the code

```
void something()
{
    int x = 5;
    randomStuffWithInt(x);
    {
        int x = 10;
        somethingWithInt(x);
    }
}
```

could be converted (alpha conversion) to

```
void something()
{
    int x = 5;
    randomStuffWithInt(x);
    int y = 10;
    somethingWithInt(y);
}
```

At runtime, it should be exactly the same speed.

Answer (score 1):

Late answer, but...  I believe there will actually be an execution impact (though not necessarily a large one) given that the run-time engine will create a local variable symbol table on the stack to house variables within the block.  If this is done in a looping context or in code otherwise requiring high speed, it may be advisable to avoid its usage.