# Why does this Hashmap Iteration not work? I get a NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, collections, nullpointerexception, iterator, hashmap

```
Map<String, String> listOfIndexes = INDEXED_TABLES.get(tableName);
Iterator it = listOfIndexes.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) { 
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pairs.getKey());
}
```

My Hashmap is like this :

```
public static  Map<String, Map<String, String>> INDEXED_TABLES = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>()
{{
    put("employee",  EMPLOYEE);
}};

public static  Map<String, String> EMPLOYEE = new HashMap<String, String>()
{{
    put("name", "Test");
    put("age", "Test");
    put("sex", "test");
}};
```

Comment: The exception's javadoc lists all possible reasons: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html

Comment: Thanks... but well, you have my data and the call. I've been trying to figure this out for a while now.

Comment: If you use a "tablename" that does not exist, you'd get an NPE on the second line.

Comment: lol... ohh Yeah I should have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are putting EMPLOYEE into the map before it has been initialized, so it will be `null` (and remain so, even if you assign something to EMPLOYEE later).

Reverse the order of the two statements.

Or, while in general [I disapprove of the double-brace-initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization/924536#924536) (hopefully, we'll get proper Collection literals in Java 8):

```
public static  Map<String, Map<String, String>> INDEXED_TABLES = 
  new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>(){{
    put("employee",  new HashMap<String, String>(){{
      put("name", "Test");
      put("age", "Test");
      put("sex", "test");
   }}
}}
```

Comment: They are in different classes. And the second one for sure is instantiated before the call is made. Let me see this though. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you outsmarted yourself: your initializers depend on the order of execution. At the time this line runs

```
put("employee",  EMPLOYEE);
```

`EMPLOYEE` is still `null`, so that's what gets put into your `Map<String,Map<String,String>>`.

You can switch the order of initializers to fix this problem. However, you would be better if you put initialization code into a separate initializer, rather than using anonymous classes with custom initializers:

```
public static  Map<String, Map<String, String>> INDEXED_TABLES = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
public static  Map<String, String> EMPLOYEE = new HashMap<String, String>();
static {
    EMPLOYEE.put("name", "Test");
    EMPLOYEE.put("age", "Test");
    EMPLOYEE.put("sex", "test");
    INDEXED_TABLES.put("employee",  EMPLOYEE);
}
```

Comment: +1. And EMPLOYEE can probably become a local variable in that static block.