# method parameters in double brace initialization?

Tags: java, method-parameters, double-brace-initialize

I'm creating a `HashMap` inline with double braces inside a function:

```
public void myFunction(String key, String value) {
    myOtherFunction(
        new JSONSerializer().serialize(
            new HashMap<String , String>() {{
                put("key", key);
                put("value", value.);
            }}
        )
    );
}
```

and I'm receiving these errors:

```
myClass.java:173: error: local variable key is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                        put("key", key);
                                   ^
myClass.java:174: error: local variable value is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
                        put("value", value);
                                     ^
2 errors
```

How can method parameters be inserted into an `Object` double brace initialized?

Comment: Are you trying to define method inside method?

Comment: @Smit i don´t think so: he is just calling a function for which he inline creates obejcts and calls member functions of them.

Comment: jQuery has spoiled me. ;)  must.put.everything...INLINE!

Comment: If you use an IDE, it would be able to auto-correct this error for you.

Comment: If your Map really contains just one key and one value, you could also do `new JSONSerializer().serialize(Collections.singletonMap(key, value))`.

Comment: [Every time someone uses double-brace initialisation, a kitten gets killed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27521360/521799)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your parameters as `final`:

```
public void myFunction(final String key, final String value)
```

Also, you might want to take a look at [Efficiency of Java "Double Brace Initialization"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/924285/758280)

Comment: bingo.  genius.  i tried it inside the initialization which gave even more errors.  didn't think to do it to the parameters.  thx!

Answer (score 1):

Compiler will complain if you use non final local variables in inner classes, fix it with this:

```
public void myFunction(final String key, final String value) {
    myOtherFunction(
        new JSONSerializer().serialize(
            new HashMap<String , String>() {{
               put("key", key);
               put ("value", value.);
            }}
        )
    );
}
```