# How to quickly and conveniently create a one element arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Is there a Utility method somewhere that can do this in 1 line? I can't find it anywhere in `Collections`, or `List`.

```
public List<String> stringToOneElementList(String s) {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add(s);
    return list;
}
```

I don't want to re-invent the wheel unless I plan on putting fancy rims on it.

Well... the type can be `T`, and not `String`. but you get the point. (with all the null checking, safety checks...etc)

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be using that method at all. The places where you are calling the method, just replace the call with the "single line" transformation you are looking for.

Comment: @RohitJain could you please specify what you mean? i'm not sure i understand. what do you mean by this "single line transformation"?

Comment: I mean, you want to transform everthing inside the method into a single line right? Well, then that method isn't really doing anything that can't be done without it. What you would do is, `return Arrays.asList(s);`. But then what's the point of that extra method? It is just acting as a delegate. Just remove it. And wherever you call `stringToOneElementList(s)`, call `Arrays.asList(s)`, that's it.

Comment: oh okay, i think i understand. well, the only reason i had that method was because i didn't know where that "magic one liner" was. hence, that's why i asked this stackoverflow question in the first place. if i already knew that one line `Arrays.asList(s)`, then why would i ask my question here on stackoverflow? i was surprised to find that this convenience method is in Arrays and not Collections.

Comment: `Arrays` is a utility class containing various other methods you might be sing from time to time. The reason this method in `Arrays` class is because, the method is really converting from `array` to a `list`. The method is defined to take var-args. So, whatever arguments you pass to it is internally converted to an array only. And then a list is created out of it. So, that's its designated place - `Arrays`.

Comment: the design in Java was to turn ANY amount of strings into lists, which includes just 1 string (but also means there's only 1 way to do so). in other languages there are more than one way to do something, so i just wanted to know the best way (in this case, only 1 way), for example, ruby, you can say "blah.first" and "blah.last" as opposed to like "blah[0]", which is very convenient and more readable. in Java, that doesn't seem to be the case. sorry, hope that made sense

Answer (score 574, accepted):

#### Fixed size `List`

The easiest way, that I know of, is to create a fixed-size single element `List` with [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) like

```
// Returns a List backed by a varargs T.
return Arrays.asList(s);
```

#### Variable size `List`

If it needs vary in size you can construct an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-java.util.Collection-) and the fixed-size`List` like

```
return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s));
```

and (in Java 7+) you can use the [diamond operator `<>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) to make it

```
return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(s));
```

#### Single Element List

Collections can return a list with a single element with list being immutable:

```
Collections.singletonList(s)
```

The benefit here is IDEs code analysis doesn't warn about single element asList(..) calls.

Comment: Be careful with this solution. You can't modify the List. If you try to for example add elements to this List, it will throw an UnsupportedOperationException!

Comment: Also be careful if `s` is an array of non-primitives. You'll end up with an list containing the array elements, rather than a list containing the array. (e.g. `Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2,3})` is OK, but `Arrays.asList(new String[]{"hello","world"})` is not.)

Comment: Collections.singletonList(elm); is more preferable as it creates immutable list.

Comment: @RavishBhagdev - not always. There are times when you may want to add stuff to the list later. In fact, I used exactly this answer's approach in a path-finding algorithm in graphs.

Comment: Intellij analysis gives the following warning "call to 'asList' with only one argument"

Comment: As of JDK9, there will be a method List.of​(E e1) that returns an immutable list (http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E-)

Comment: A very important drawback of the first approach is that if you try to convert it to ArrayList later, you'll get a ClassCastException because `Arrays.asList returns a List implementation, but it's not a java.util.ArrayList. It happens to have a classname of ArrayList, but that's a nested class within Arrays - a completely different type from java.util.ArrayList`

Comment: @RavishBhagdev Why would it be preferable to create an immutable list? Most of the time when I create a list with one element I want to keep adding elements to it later

Answer (score 393):

```
Collections.singletonList(object)
```

the list created by this method is immutable.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA automatically recommends this instead of `Arrays.asList(object)`.

Comment: Note that the list created by this method is immutable.

Comment: so you didn't take the time to write one line of the consequences of this call? Immutable list

Comment: Please mark this as an accepted answer. This is way better than Arrays.asList.

Answer (score 87):

You can use the utility method `Arrays.asList` and feed that result into a new `ArrayList`.

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s));
```

Other options:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Collections.nCopies(1, s));
```

and

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Collections.singletonList(s));
```

- [`ArrayList(Collection)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)) constructor.
- [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) method.
- [`Collections.nCopies`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#nCopies(int,%20T)) method.
- [`Collections.singletonList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonList(T)) method.

With Java 7+, you may use the "diamond operator", replacing `new ArrayList<String>(...)` with `new ArrayList<>(...)`.

**Java 9**

If you're using Java 9+, you can use the [`List.of` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E-):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(List.of(s));
```

Regardless of the use of each option above, you may choose not to use the `new ArrayList<>()` wrapper if you don't need your list to be mutable.

Comment: I'm surprised you are the only one to mention `Collections.singletonList`.

Comment: I'm even more surprised that @AndyJ posted `Collections.singletonList` after my comment and got 2x more votes than your answer which already had it and is there since 3 years... Always fun to stumble on old comments  .

Comment: I'm surprised no one but you mentioned List.of(s)

Answer (score 37):

With Java 8 Streams:

```
Stream.of(object).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

or if you need a set:

```
Stream.of(object).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Comment: You can also use Guava's `Sets.newHashSet(objects)` to create a new set.

Answer (score 22):

The other answers all use `Arrays.asList()`, which returns an unmodifiable list (an `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown if you try to add or remove an element). To get a mutable list you can wrap the returned list in a new `ArrayList` as a couple of answers point out, but a cleaner solution is to use [Guava's](https://github.com/google/guava) [Lists.newArrayList()](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#newArrayList()) (available since at least [Guava 10](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/index.html), released in 2011).

For example:

```
Lists.newArrayList("Blargle!");
```

Comment: This is not working if given element implements Iterable<T>, for example: `Lists.newArrayList(Paths.get("/usr/local/this/is/not/single/element"))`; what you want is create array with single path element, however, what you get is a list contains 7 path element.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes by default [Java will choose the most specific method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5), which in this case is `Lists#newArrayList(Iterable<? extends E> elements)`. You can do `Lists.newArrayList(new Path[] {Paths.get("/usr/local/this/is/not/single/‌​element")})` to explicitly call the vararg method, or just construct an empty list (`List<Path> p = Lists.newArrayList()`) and add the element (`p.add(Paths.get("/usr/local/this/is/not/single/‌​element"))`).

Answer (score 16):

Very simply:

```
Arrays.asList("Hi!")
```

Answer (score 5):

Seeing as Guava gets a mention, I thought I would also suggest [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) (formerly known as GS Collections).

The following examples all return a `List` with a single item.

```
Lists.mutable.of("Just one item");
Lists.mutable.with("Or use with");
Lists.immutable.of("Maybe it must be immutable?");
Lists.immutable.with("And use with if you want");
```

There are similar methods for other collections.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another alternative is [double brace initialization](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization), e.g.

```
new ArrayList<String>() {{ add(s); }};
```

but [it is inefficient and obscure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285). Therefore only suitable:

- in code that doesn't mind memory leaks, such as most unit tests and other short-lived programs;
- and if none of the other solutions apply, which I think implies you've scrolled all the way down here looking to populate a different type of container than the ArrayList in the question.

Comment: -1. Not only is it inferior, it is also invalid. Passing a list that was instantiated this way around will result in that the object that created it will not be garbage collected. Even if you think you've got the problem isolated and contained in your mind, and tell yourself it's safe to use the double-brace because it looks so damn cool, it's ill-advised at best. Whoever finds value in this answer other than recreationally (and those who find recreational value in it already know about this) is potentially going to go ahead and write that in their project.

Comment: @BenBarkay I don't see what information your comment adds to the discussion in the first link. An inefficient program is not an invalid program. I still find value in this answer for remembering why not to write this construct in projects.

Comment: I am going to avoid the discussion around validity because it's likely going to be a semantic-related one (valid to the problem vs. valid in absolute terms). The value that this comment adds is that it attaches a warning of weight that is more closely equal to the danger, right next to the idea itself. Inefficiency, obscurity and inconvenience are not the primary dysfunction of this technique.

Comment: If you edit your answer to reflect that use of this technique will result in memory leaks if the list is shared between instances, I will +1 (resulting in +-0).

Comment: This approach creates a subclass of ArrayList ... Think about it.