# Map a generic method over a list and produce list of results

Tags: java, generics, functional-programming

I have a generic method (called `map`) which takes a parameter of type `Funcn` where `Funcn<K,T>` is an interface having only one method, `T eval(K)`, which takes a `K` and returns a `T`. In `map`, I need use the `Funcn` to iterate through a `List<K>` (which is defined in the `main` method — I use `this` in the `map` to access it) and apply the `Funcn` to each element in the list. Finally, a new `List<T>` of all the results of `eval` should be returned. However, I am not sure how this can be done, since I am unfamiliar with the syntax of generics.

```
/// the Funcn interface ///
package arrayList;
import java.util.*;

public interface Funcn <K,T> {
    public T eval(K k);
}

/// the generic map method(in its own class) ///
public java.util.ArrayList<T> map(Funcn<T,K> fn){
    for(T value:this){
        //fn must be applied to all elements in 'this'  
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `this` referring to a instance of a `Iterable` type? Please give more context.

Comment: Yes. It is used as the list is defined in the main method and cannot be passed as a parameter to the function.

Comment: I am so confused as to your actual question, but it LOOKs like you are making your own Map object....why aren't you using a Hashmap, TreeMap, etc if that is the case?

Comment: Map means the map function I assume, sometimes called apply, which applies the function **f** to every value of a collection **C**.

Comment: Ahhhhh, yep you are right @reindeer

Answer (score 1):

### The problem in your code

In your code, the interface `Funcn<K,T>` declares a method `eval` that takes a `K` as an argument and returns a `T`.  Note that `K` is the first type parameter and `T` is the second.

```
public interface Funcn <K,T> {
    public T eval(K k);
}
```

In the declaration of your `map` method, though, you've got the type parameters to your `Funcn` reversed:

```
public java.util.ArrayList<T> map(Funcn<T,K> fn){ /* … */ }
//                                      * *
```

This means that `fn.eval` takes a `T` and returns a `K`.  Instead, it should be `Funcn<K,T> fn` so that `fn.eval` takes a `K` and returns a `T`. This would explain the error message that you mentioned in a comment: "The method `apply(K)` in the type `Function<T,K>` is not applicable for the arguments `(T)`"  (It wouldn't explain why you've got `Function` in one place and `Funcn` in another, though.  Are you showing us the real code?)

### In general

Swapping the order of those arguments will solve your immediate problem, but in general the type parameters are a little bit more complicated. It's tricky to get the input and output types for these generic functions exactly right, since you should be able map a function that expects an argument of type C over a list whose elements are of a subtype of C.  The comments in the code explain this in a bit more detail.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MapExample {

    /**
     * A Function maps an input to an output.
     */
    interface Function<InputType,OutputType> {
        OutputType call( InputType input );
    }

    /**
     * Map returns a list of elements obtained by applying the function
     * to each element of the input list.  The input and output types 
     * of the function do not need to align exactly with the type of 
     * elements in the input list;  but the function's input type must
     * be some supertype of the element type of the input list.  Similarly,
     * the output type of the function does not need to be the element type
     * of the output list;  but it must extend that type so that the result
     * of the function can be stored in the output list.
     */
    public static <OutputType,InputType> List<OutputType> map(
            final Function<? super InputType,? extends OutputType> function,
            final List<? extends InputType> list ) {
        final List<OutputType> results = new ArrayList<>( list.size() );
        for ( InputType in : list ) { 
            results.add( function.call( in ));
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // f takes an integer n to the string "*<n+1>*" (where <n+1> is the value of n+1). 
        Function<Integer,String> f = new Function<Integer, String>() {
            @Override
            public String call(Integer input) {
                return "*"+new Integer( input + 1 ).toString()+"*";
            }
        };
        System.out.println( map( f, Arrays.asList( 1, 3, 6, 8 )));
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
[*2*, *4*, *7*, *9*]
```

---

### (Optional) A case for instance initializers

As an aside, I find that some of these functional problems are nice places to use instance initialization blocks in objects.  While the implementation above creates the `results` list, then populates, and then returns it, you could also have the body of `map` be:

```
return new ArrayList<OutputType>( list.size() ) {{
    for ( final InputType in : list ) {
        add( function.call( in ));
    }
}};
```

which I kind of like, although you'll get a warning about the fact that the new (anonymous) class doesn't have a serialization ID, so you'd either need to `@SuppressWarnings("serial")` on the `map` method, or add an ID to the class.  Those might not be so desirable, though.  There are other issues with this kind of object too, though, as discussed in [Efficiency of Java "Double Brace Initialization"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/924285/1281433).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that T is the input of *Funcn*, and K the return type of it. It then has to return a list of K to work, else the generic signature of *Funcn* is useless.

```
public java.util.ArrayList<K> map(Funcn<T,K> fn){

    ArrayList<K> lst = new ArrayList<K>();

    for(T value:this){
        lst.add( fn.eval(value) );
    }
    return lst;    
}
```

Comment: I have tried this already, however I keep getting this error: The method apply(K) in the type Function<T,K> is not applicable for the arguments (T)

Comment: Can you post the **Funcn** interface with the *eval* signature?