# Different Style object initialization with scala

Tags: scala

When I using java there are something like double bracket initialization that actually make some runtime trade off. In scala I discover the simple way to initiate object property like

```
val button1: Button = new Button
button1.setText("START")
button1.setPrefWidth(100)
```

Which can be rewriten to

```
val button2: Button = new Button {
setText("PAUSE")
setPrefWidth(100)
}
```

Is these make any difference from performance or something else?

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that in the first case you instantiate a new `Button` object and set its properties to some values (text = "START" and width = 100) and in the second case you create an anonymous class that inherits from `Button` and initialize its properties in its anonymous initializer (or constructor, not sure - Java's anonymous classes cannot have constructors).

The second case can be roughly rewritten like this (if it weren't an anonymous class):

```
class MyButton extends Button {
  //constructor
  setText("START")
  setPrefWidth(100)
}
```

And when you call `new MyButton` you get an instance of `MyButton` with text set as "START" and prefWidth set as 100.

If you come from Java background consider this analogy:

```
Button button = new Button() {
    //anonymous initializer
    {
        setText("START");
        setPrefWidth(100);
    }
};
```

Comment: I recently read this post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization
so, is there any performance impact with that initialization in scala?

Comment: I mean, is scala implementation of anonymous class differ from java?

Comment: I have actually no idea about the performance of this. I think I'll try to measure it soon

Comment: Ok, just tested. Initialization of 1000 `Button()` objects took approximately ~78 ms on my laptop. 1000 `Button{}` objects took approximately ~397 ms. 10 measurements for each case. So yes, there is a performance impact but it's not that critical to reject this type of initialization