# Better way to initialize Map in constructor in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, constructor, initialization

I am trying to initialize a Map to zeros in a class. I am doing that in this way:

```
public class A{   
   private final Map<String,Integer> myMap;

   public A(){

       this.myMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>() {
           {
              put("a",0);
              put("b",0);
            }
       };  
     } 
}
```

My question: Is this a good implementation? Is there anything wrong with this? Or is there any better way to implement this?

Comment: how about you `put` a and b it after you initialized it.

Comment: Agree with @Rod_Algonquin. In your case that's the simplest.

Comment: you mean in side the constructor myMap.put("a",0) and myMap("b",0) ? isn't the same? or did I missed something?

Comment: If you've declared `final Map` then it means you want/need the varable `myMap` should not be reassigned. If you also need that it should not allow more data add/removal/update, then you should change this design to use an unmodifiable map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What Rod_Algonquin meant was:

```
public class A {
   private final Map<String,Integer> myMap;

   public A() {

      this.myMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
      this.myMap.put("a",0);
      this.myMap.put("b",0);
   } 
}
```

---

Following up on Luiggi Mendoza's comment, since the `Map` is declared `final`, you might have meant for the map to be unmodifiable, but `final` does *not* assure that. This will:

```
public class A {
   private final Map<String,Integer> myMap;

   public A() {
      Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
      map.put("a",0);
      map.put("b",0);
      this.myMap = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. @MickMnemonic is also similar to this.

Comment: I don't see how this answer addresses the "Is this a good implementation? Is there anything wrong with this?" part of the question. Also, an unmodifiable map that only holds zeros sounds pretty useless; I would assume the OP wants to initialize the map with zeros and later on change some of the values.

Answer (score 2):

A better way would be to simply put the values in after you've initialized the map:

```
myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("a",0);
myMap.put("b",0);
```

What your current version is doing is that it's using an *instance initializer* block (a.k.a. [double brace initialization](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DoubleBraceInitialization)), which creates an unnecessary anonymous class in the background. There is no real benefit in doing so here. On the contrary, it will likely cause a small [performance hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization).

Answer (score 0):

If your real goal is the creation of an immutable `Map`, I highly recommend using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained)'s [ImmutableMap.Builder](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.Builder.html)