# How can I pass a new single value map as an argument?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary

I have a container that tracks Hosts, Files, and parts of each file:

```
private static Map<String, Map<String, ArrayList<FileShard>>> globalFileShardMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, ArrayList<FileShard>>>();
```

I want to put a new entry into this, and am doing so like:

```
 // filename and shard are known
 ArrayList<FileShard> initShard = new ArrayList<FileShard>();
 initShard.add(shard);

 Map<String, ArrayList<FileShard>> initMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<FileShard>>();
 initMap.put(filename,initShard);

 globalFileShardMap.put(Node.getLocal().getHostname(), initMap);
```

Is there a way to condense this to a single line, and pass in the new inner Map as a parameter to `globalFileShardMap.put`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap(K,%20V)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way of doing it in one line without creating any anonymous classes.

```
globalFileShardMap.put(Node.getLocal().getHostname(), 
    new HashMap<>(Collections.singletonMap(filename, 
    new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(shard)))));
```

This requires Java 7 for the diamond `<>`.

If you don't actually need a `HashMap` and an `ArrayList` (i.e. any old `Map` and `List` will do) you can just get rid of `new HashMap<>` and `new ArrayList<>`.

Answer (score 1):

In-line transformation would be -

```
globalFileShardMap.put(Node.getLocal().getHostname(), new HashMap<String, ArrayList<FileShard>>(){{
     put(filename, new ArrayList<FileShard>(){{add(shard);}});
}});
```

Comment: I'm not terribly well versed in java - what do `{{` and `}}` do?

Comment: This creates anonymous inner class with an instance initializer (also known as "double brace initialization")

Comment: I suggest avoiding the extra class by using `Arrays.asList` for the list. After checking out the question again, you could actually just pass shards to the constructor of `ArrayList`. Overall you could avoid the extra classes by using the current class's initializer, rather than subclassing map and list. More on why you should try and avoid "double brance initialization" [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization)

Comment: Arrays.asList returns fixed-size list. Here in this case `List` with single element did not make much sense to me. Where `ArrayList` is much more flexible.