# Java 8 Streams API to filter Map entries

Tags: collections, java-8, java-stream

I have a the following container in Java that I need to work on

```
Map<String, List<Entry<Parameter, String>>>
```

Where `Parameter` is an enumerated type defined as follows:

```
public enum Parameter {
    Param1,
    Param2,
    Param3
}
```

The code below shows how I initialize the map structure - effectively putting 2 rows in the container.

```
    Map<String, List<Entry<Parameter, String>>> map2 = new HashMap<String, List<Entry<Parameter, String>>>() {{
        put("SERVICE1", new ArrayList<Entry<Parameter, String>>(){{
            add (new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(Parameter.Param1,"val1"));
            add (new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(Parameter.Param2,"val2"));
            add (new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(Parameter.Param3,"val3"));
        }});
        put("SERVICE2", new ArrayList<Entry<Parameter, String>>(){{
            add (new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(Parameter.Param1,"val4"));
            add (new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(Parameter.Param2,"val5"));
            add (new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(Parameter.Param3,"val6"));
        }});
    }};
```

I need to use the java 8 streams api to find the `val1` and `val2` values from "`SERVICE1`" but I do not know the correct java streams filter and mapping syntax.

The nearest thing I can come up with is the following, but this only filters at the top level and it returns a list of lists rather than the list of `Parameter.Param1,"val1"` & `Parameter.Param2,"val3"` that I am looking for from the `SERVICE1` row.

```
    List<List<Entry<Parameter, String>>> listOfLists = myMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(next -> next.getKey().equals("SERVICE1"))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    listOfLists.size();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only need the "val1" and "val2" values, you can first use `getOrDefault` to get the corresponding list, and then filter on the entries' keys to get entries with `Param1` or `Param2` as key, and finally apply map again to get the values of these entries.

```
List<String> list =
    myMap.getOrDefault("SERVICE1", Collections.emptyList())
         .stream()
         .filter(e -> e.getKey() == Parameter.Param1 || e.getKey() == Parameter.Param2)
         .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Also you might be interested to look at [Efficiency of Java "Double Brace Initialization"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization)

Comment: Nice, but is there some way of achieving the same result leaving in the current top level filter(next -> next.getKey().equals("SERVICE1")) that I currently have in place or is that always going to return a list of lists.  I think the code I wrote is almost there but there is some sort of way of just returning the first of these list of lists.

Comment: @johnco3 Well yes, use `flatMap` instead of `map`, and filter the entries the same way `.filter(next -> next.getKey().equals("SERVICE1")).flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()) .filter(e -> e.getKey() == Parameter.Param1 || e.getKey() == Parameter.Param2).map(Map.Entry::getValue).collect(...)`. But there is no benefit  to go with this approach since you will only have one list because you are interested in a mapping with a specific key.

Comment: ... unless the filtering on the keys might lead multiple lists like `next -> next.getKey().startsWith("SERVICE")` for instance.

Comment: Yes you got it right, In fact the actual case will be when next.getKey() is not SERVICE1, I will need to filter different Params