# How do I fix these double braces

Tags: java, double-brace-initialize

Hello I am trying to tidy up some code and I have stumbled across some double braces. I realize that this is a sin and that I should fix this. However, I have no idea where to begin. Can anyone help?

```
private SelectItem notifyTypeItem = new SelectItem();

notifyTypeItem.setTitle("Default Notification");
    notifyTypeItem.setWidth("100%");
    notifyTypeItem.setValueMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, String>() {{
                   put("0", "None");
                   put("1", "Subtle");
                   put("2", "Intrusive");
               }}
    );
```

Comment: *I realize that this is a sin and that I should fix this.* how did you come to realize this, if you don't know how to "fix" it?

Comment: I am using IntelliJ and it has thrown an automated warning. Before asking this question I have conducted some research myself and I am aware of the problems this can cause but most of the solutions do not seem to cover this type. I am attempting to apply my knowledge but I cannot seem to solve this problem. @Tim

Comment: I am still not sure how you can recognize a problem with this syntax without understanding the purpose of it. I am assuming you don't understand the purpose because if you did you would also realize how simple it would be to rewrite it to "simpler" code

Comment: It is not my system and I am still very much a beginner in programming. I am still unsure of "Maps" and "HashMaps". If it would serve me better to conduct research on them I will gladly do so as I am always willing to learn. @tim

Comment: Have a look at [Double Brace Initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java) - it may not be a sin.

Comment: Make sure you grok the difference between named classes and anonymous inner classes and you should understand that "double braces" is just a visual red herring from using a certain feature of Java in another, and a solution becomes more apparent. Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891568/alternative-to-double-brace-initialization) too. It's not an exact duplicate, but it's damn close. You should be able to directly apply the lesson.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon Have a look at [Why you shouldn't use the double brace initializer](https://blog.nishtahir.com/2015/09/27/why-you-shouldnt-use-the-double-brace-initializer/) for a good overview of why it's generally not a good idea. Long story short: inner anonymous classes and implicit references to `Outer.this` and all the fun memory leaks they can cause.

Comment: If you're using Java 9 or later: `notifyTypeItem.setValueMap(Map.of("0", "None", "1", "Subtle", "2", "Intrusive"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand how to fix it, you should first understand what it's doing. For this, you'll need to know about two things:

1. [Anonymous sub-classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html)
2. [Instance initializer blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)

The TL;DR of how to fix it is just to split those `put` calls and initialization out from the setter:

```
Map<String, String> valueMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
valueMap.put("0", "None");
valueMap.put("1", "Subtle");
valueMap.put("2", "Intrusive");
notifyTypeItem.setValueMap(valueMap);
```

Read on for an explanation of what's happening and why it can be a bad approach.

### Anonymous Sub-classes

An anonymous class is generally just a class without a name. For example, you can create anonymous instances of an interface like `Runnable`:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Do something
    }
};
r.run(); // Does that something
```

Similarly, you can create anonymous instances of abstract and concrete classes too. For example, it's very common to create an anonymous instance of `ThreadLocal`:

```
private static ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat> localIsoDateFormat = new ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>() {

    @Override
    protected SimpleDateFormat initialValue() {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }
}
```

This is useful when you don't need a full, dedicated class to override a method or two, similar to creating anonymous instances of interfaces with only one method.

### Instance Initializer Blocks

An instance initializer block allows you to execute initializers outside of your constructor. For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    
    private final String s;
    {
        s = "My Class String";
    }

    public String getS() { return s; }
}
```

It's essentially a stand-in for a constructor, and it's generally unnecessary, so you rarely see it. It can almost always be moved to a constructor instead.

### Combining Them

Your example combines them. It's creating an anonymous subclass of `LinkedHashMap`, then it's also using an initializer block. More properly formatted, your code is:

```
Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>() {
    {
        put("0", "None");
        put("1", "Subtle");
        put("2", "Intrusive");
    }
};
```

It's an anonymous instance of `LinkedHashMap` with an instance initializer block that does the `put` calls.

### Why is it bad?

For the same reason that you need to [be careful creating anonymous classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864853/when-exactly-is-it-leak-safe-to-use-anonymous-inner-classes): references to the enclosing class instance.

Anonymous classes are notorious for being the source of memory leaks in your application. Your code appears to be in a non-`static` context. This means that the anonymous `LinkedHashMap` subclass you create will have an implicit reference to the class that your method is sitting in. For example, if your method is in `MyClass`:

```
public class MyClass {
    private SelectItem notifyTypeItem = new SelectItem();

    public void foo() {
        notifyTypeItem.setTitle("Default Notification");
        notifyTypeItem.setWidth("100%");
        notifyTypeItem.setValueMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, String>() {{
                   put("0", "None");
                   put("1", "Subtle");
                   put("2", "Intrusive");
               }}
        );
    }
}
```

The newly created `LinkedHashMap` subclass (`MyClass$1` will be the "class name", if you can call it such a thing) will have a reference to the enclosing `MyClass` instance. In some cases, this may be fine. But if you're creating the `notifyTypeItem` with the intention of passing it to something else and throwing away your `MyClass` instance, then you'll be creating a memory leak in your application. The `MyClass` instance will be referenced by the `MyClass$1` instance, and the `SelectItem` will reference the `MyClass$1` instance, so the `MyClass` instance will never be garbage collected until the `SelectItem` instance is no longer referenced. If `MyClass` has several other references besides the `SelectItem`, then that will only increase the total memory a single `MyClass` instance consumes, and lead to more memory leak issues.

---

### References

Here are some relevant links:

- [Anonymous Classes Java Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) (Java trail, docs.oracle.com)
- [Initializing Fields Java Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) (Java trail, docs.oracle.com)
- [What is Double Brace initialization in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java) (SO question, stackoverflow.com)
- [Why you shouldn't use the double brace initializer](https://blog.nishtahir.com/2015/09/27/why-you-shouldnt-use-the-double-brace-initializer/) (blog post by Nish Tahir, blog.nishtahir.com)
- [When exactly is it leak safe to use (anonymous) inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10864853/when-exactly-is-it-leak-safe-to-use-anonymous-inner-classes) (SO question, stackoverflow.com)

Comment: `notifyItemType` is being passed through so the Class instance is being dropped. This code is causing a memory leak. I will continue to read up on this but you have opened my eays. Thanks