# Java `InvocationTargetException` with class instantiation by reflection

Tags: java, reflection, nullpointerexception, invocationtargetexception

The problem I'm experiencing is thus: I have a series of classes that are collected via annotations.  They all reside in the same folder, and if they have the particular annotation, they are instantiated via the [`Reflections` library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections).  While these classes are being instantiated, there is a static initializer that calls a static factory, which builds some structure.  Java will throw the `InvocationTargetException` error while trying to obtain the factory created object.  More specifically when I output the stacktrace for the `ITE` it points directly to the static initializer that asks the factory for the object.

Below is the code I use to replicate the issue.

I have an annotation: `InferenceRule.java`

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface funRule {
    String ruleName();
    String ruleType();
    String analyze() default "node";
}
```

I then apply that annotation to some number of classes in the package `inference.rules`:

```
@InferenceRule(ruleName = "assign", ruleType = "term")
public class Assign extends NodeAnalyzer {
    public Assign() {super();}
    public Assign(String... args) { super(args); }
    public Rule gatherAllCOnstraints(InstructionNode node) {
        // use the Identifier object here.
    }
    // rest of class here
}
```

The `NodeAnalyzer` class, the super of the `Assign` class above:

```
public abstract class NodeAnalyzer {
    protected Identifier identifier;

    protected NodeAnalyzer() {
        // Construct things here
    }

    protected NodeAnalyzer(String... args) {
        // Construct other things here
    }

    // Construct common things here
    {
        this.identifier = IdentifierFactory.getIdentifier();
    }
    // rest of class here
}
```

The `Assign` class is instantiated in the `Inference` class, as described below:

```
public class Inference {
    public final String NODE_ANALYSIS = "NODE";
    public static final String INFERENCE_PACKAGE = "inference.rules";
    private final Map<String, NodeAnalyzer> nodeAnalyzer = new HashMap<>();
    private final Map<String, EdgeAnalyzer> edgeAnalyzer = new HashMap<>();
    public Inference() {

    }
    // other non-interesting things here

    private void loadRules() {
        Reflections reflection = new Reflections(INFERENCE_PACKAGE);
        Set<Class<?>> annotated = reflection.getTypesAnnotatedWith(InferenceRule.class);

        for(Class<?> clazz : annotated) {
            try {
                String name = clazz.getAnnotation(InferenceRule.class).ruleName();
                String type = clazz.getAnnotation(InferenceRule.class).ruleType();
                String analyze = clazz.getAnnotation(InferenceRule.class).analyze();
                if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(analyze, NODE_ANALYSIS)) {
                    final NodeAnalyzer newInstance = (NodeAnalyzer) clazz.getConstructor(InferenceType.class).newInstance(InferenceType.valueOf(type));
                    this.nodeAnalyzer.put(name, newInstance);
                }
                // handle other cases...
            } catch(InvocationTargetException ite) {
                // For debugging, only
                ite.printStackTrace();
                logger.error(ite.getCause.getMessage());
                logger.error(ite.getTargetException.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, from the instantiation path in `Assign` and `NodeAnalyzer`, it must call the `IdentifierFactory` class:

```
public class IdentifierFactory {
    private static final Identifier identifier;
    static {
        if (ConfigFactory.getConfig().isDebEnabled()) {
            identifier = new DBIdentifier();
        } else {
            identifier = new NaiveIdentifier();
        }
    }

    public static Identifier getIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }
}
```

The `NaiveIdentifier` class:

```
public class NaiveIdentifier {
    private Set<Integer> unknowns = new HashSet<Integer>() {{
        unknowns.add(0);
        // add more here.
    };

    public NaiveIdentifier() {} // empty default constructor
}
```

The `ConfigFactory` class follows a similar pattern as the `IdentifierFactory` class.  It builds a config based on certain input.

The exact exception thrown looks like:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at phases.inference.Inference.loadRules(Inference.java:197)
    at phases.inference.Inference.<init>(Inference.java:76)
    at phases.PhaseFacade$PHASES.getPhase(PhaseFacade.java:27)
    at phases.PhaseFacade.<init>(PhaseFacade.java:42)
    at compilation.Compiler.runPhases(Compiler.java:126)
    at compilation.Compiler.runAllOps(Compiler.java:118)
    at Main.main(Main.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at phases.inference.rules.NodeAnalyzer.<init>(NodeAnalyzer.java:35)
    at phases.inference.rules.Assign.<init>(Assign.java:22)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at typesystem.identification.NaiveIdentifier$1.<init>(NaiveIdentifier.java:23)
    at typesystem.identification.NaiveIdentifier.<init>(NaiveIdentifier.java:22)
    at typesystem.identification.IdentifierFactory.<clinit>(IdentifierFactory.java:25)
    ... 13 more
```

and:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at phases.inference.Inference.loadRules(Inference.java:197)
    at phases.inference.Inference.<init>(Inference.java:76)
    at phases.PhaseFacade$PHASES.getPhase(PhaseFacade.java:27)
    at phases.PhaseFacade.<init>(PhaseFacade.java:42)
    at compilation.Compiler.runPhases(Compiler.java:126)
    at compilation.Compiler.runAllOps(Compiler.java:118)
    at Main.main(Main.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class typesystem.identification.IdentifierFactory
    at phases.inference.rules.NodeAnalyzer.<init>(NodeAnalyzer.java:35)
    at phases.inference.rules.Assign.<init>(Assign.java:18)
    ... 11 more
```

From these, I cannot adequately discern what the root cause is.  To further complicate this, I have tried to run this using other input files and it works just fine on those.

Comment: The root cause appears to be an NPE thrown in the constructor for the `NaiveIdentifier` class (or possibly an anonymous inner class).  Could you please edit the question to include the code of this class?  The second error, with message 'Could not initialize class...' is what happens when you try to load a class that has already failed static initialization. Java doesn't bother making a second attempt to initialize these.

Comment: I added the relevant code.  After to stepping through *every* line of code, it appeared that the problem was with the instantiation of the `HashSet` in `NaiveIdentifier`.  I don't understand why that would throw the NPE.

Comment: The double-curly brace initialization is an anti-pattern, hiding what actually happens behind the scenes (creating an instance of an inner class subclassing the type you actually want to instantiate), all for the questionable advantage of being able to write `add(element);` instead of `fieldName.add(element);`. Ironically, you are not even using that advantage as you have written `unknowns.add(0);`, not saving any character, but breaking the entire code by accessing the field `unknowns` from the constructor of the inner class, before the constructed object has been assigned to the field.

Comment: @Holger: any reason you didn't write that comment as an answer?

Comment: @LukeWoodward: good question. I suppose, I wasn’t sure whether this is the issue, especially as there is a typo in the OP’s code right at this place. Thinking about it again, this must be the issue, so I added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code

```
public class NaiveIdentifier {
    private Set<Integer> unknowns = new HashSet<Integer>() {{
        unknowns.add(0);
        // add more here.
    }}; // ( <- added missing brace here)

    public NaiveIdentifier() {} // empty default constructor
}
```

is using the “Double Curly Brace Initialization” anti-pattern. Usually, this anti-pattern is used to save some typing in source code:

```
public class NaiveIdentifier {
    private Set<Integer> unknowns = new HashSet<Integer>() {{
        // yeah, we saved writing the nine characters "unknowns."
        add(0);
        // add more here.
    }};

    public NaiveIdentifier() {} // empty default constructor
}
```

at the expense of creating a new subclass of the collection class and potentially creating memory leaks as inner classes hold references to their outer class instance, as discussed in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/924285/2711488).

As an ironic twist, you have not omitted the characters `unknowns.`, thus not only not taken any advantage of this anti-pattern, but created this bug, as you are accessing the field supposed to be initialized with the constructed set instance from within the set’s constructor. In other words, your code is equivalent to the following code:

```
public class NaiveIdentifier {
    private Set<Integer> unknowns;
    {
      Set<Integer> temp = new HashSet<Integer>() {{
        unknowns.add(0);
        // add more here.
      }};
      unknowns = temp;
    }

    public NaiveIdentifier() {} // empty default constructor
}
```

which makes it clear, why this code fails with a `NullPointerException`.

You could fix this by using the anti-pattern consistently, i.e. remove the `unknowns.` characters to change the outer instance field access to a superclass invocation (like in the second code example above), however, now that the characters are there, you could easily change the code to use a clean initializer without the anti-pattern:

```
public class NaiveIdentifier {
    private Set<Integer> unknowns = new HashSet<Integer>();
    {
        unknowns.add(0);
        // add more here.
    }

    public NaiveIdentifier() {} // empty default constructor
}
```

When using single curly braces, you are not creating an inner class subclass of `HashSet`, but just defining an initializer that will be added to the constructor of `NaiveIdentifier`, executed in the expected program text order, first, the initializer `unknowns = new HashSet<Integer>()`, then the `unknowns.add(…);` statements.

For simple initialization statements, you may consider the alternative

```
public class NaiveIdentifier {
    private Set<Integer> unknowns = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3 …));

    public NaiveIdentifier() {} // empty default constructor
}
```