# Understanding of results produced by parallel Java 8 streams

Tags: java-8, java-stream

Not getting the same results every time when I run a parallel stream for reading a file and processing it.

I have data regarding pizzas and want to have a count of different variables using Map and global variables. I should use global variables only. But when I run my code, I am getting different results every time. The input file is not modified at all.

```
package Assignment;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class GlobalVariables {
    static int vegPizzas = 0;
    static int N_V_Pizzas = 0;
    static int Size_regular = 0;
    static int Size_medium = 0;
    static int Size_large = 0;
    static int Cheese_Burst = 0;
    static int Cheese_regular = 0;
    static int cheap_cheese = 0;

    static Stream<String> reader;

    static int rows = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            reader = Files.lines(Paths.get("data/SampleData.csv")).parallel();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        reader.map(x -> x.split(","))
            .filter(x -> (!(x[0].equals("NULL") || x[1].equals("NULL") || x[2].equals("NULL")     || x[3].equals("NULL"))))
            .map(x -> updateCounts(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        printResults();
        System.out.println(rows);//to have a count of rows after filtering of NULL values is     done
    }

    private static void printResults() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("veg pizzas: " + vegPizzas);
        System.out.println("non veg pizzas: " + N_V_Pizzas);
        System.out.println("regular: " + Size_regular + " medium: " + Size_medium + " large: "    +Size_large);
        System.out.println("cheese burst pizzas: " + Cheese_Burst);
        System.out.println("regular cheese burst: " + Cheese_regular);
        System.out.println("cheaper cheese burst: " + cheap_cheese);
    }

    private static Object updateCounts(String[] x) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//      static int vegPizzas = 0;
//      static int N_V_Pizzas = 0;
//      static int Size_regular = 0;
//      static int Size_medium = 0;
//      static int Size_large = 0;
//      static int Cheese_Burst = 0;
//      static int Cheese_regular = 0;
//      static int cheap_cheese = 0;
        rows++;
        int flag_regular = 0;
        if(x[9].equals("Y")) {
            vegPizzas++;
        }else if(x[9].equals("N")) {
            N_V_Pizzas++;
        }

        if(x[6].equals("R")) {
            Size_regular++;
            flag_regular = 1;
        }
        else if(x[6].equals("M")) {
            Size_medium++;
        }
        else if(x[6].equals("L")) {
            Size_large++;
        }

        if(x[5].equals("Y")) {
            Cheese_Burst++;
            if(flag_regular == 1) {
                Cheese_regular++;
            }
            if(Integer.parseInt(x[7]) < 500) {
                cheap_cheese++;
            }
        }

        return x;
    }

}
```

//True results or expected results (counts of each variety)

veg: 5303
non-veg: 1786 
regular: 1779 medium: 2660 large: 2650
cheese-burst: 3499
regular cheese burst: 900
cheaper cheese burst: 598

//Run -1 results

veg pizzas: 5296
non veg pizzas: 1785
regular: 1779 medium: 2660 large: 2649
cheese burst pizzas: 3498
regular cheese burst: 900
cheaper cheese burst: 598
7060

//Run-2 results

veg pizzas: 5294
non veg pizzas: 1786
regular: 1779 medium: 2659 large: 2648
cheese burst pizzas: 3497
regular cheese burst: 900
cheaper cheese burst: 598
7055

//Run-3 results

veg pizzas: 5303
non veg pizzas: 1786
regular: 1779 medium: 2660 large: 2650
cheese burst pizzas: 3499
regular cheese burst: 900
cheaper cheese burst: 598
7086

I did go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900204/java-8-parallel-stream-issue). I could not relate my problem with the problem posted in that link. I did notice that if I create a sequential stream I am getting the expected results. Any lead on this can be helpful.

Comment: I got the answer. I did not make the method thread safe as described in the earlier link posted at the end of the above question. Now I am getting the same expected results. I am new to this community, so can someone suggest me if I should remove this question or let it be? If i have remove it then to do so? Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `updateCounts(String[] x)` method, called by the `map` step of the `Stream` pipeline is not thread-safe, and it updates `static` variables.

So when it is called by multiple threads concurrently, it is expected to produce different results in each run (i.e. the final values of the `static` variables will be different in each run).

The `Function` passed to `map` shouldn't have side effects, especially not when used in a parallel `Stream`.

A better way to make this computation with `Stream`s:

- Create a `PizzaStatistics` class having all the original static counter variables as instance variables.
- `updateCounts` (which should be renamed) would return a new `PizzaStatistics` instance where the relevant counters are set to 1. It won't update any static variables.
- The Stream pipeline would use the terminal operation `reduce` to produce a single `PizzaStatistics` instance that contains the totals.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make only variables rather than methods being synchronized? So that if one variable is being edited by one thread, another thread can work on another variable in the same method. I can think of one methodology where every variable update is done in different methods and those methods are thread safe but no the updateCounts(String[ ] x) method

Comment: @HackChamp you could make the `updateCounts` method synchronized, but it would still be bad usage of Streams.

Comment: I have edited my earlier comment. Is that(mentioned in earlier comment) a better way of doing things?

Comment: @HackChamp you can change `updateCounts` to call a different synchronized static method for each variable it has to update. This way `updateCounts` itself won't have to be synchronized

Comment: @HackChamp it's still not good practice for using the Stream pipeline this way, since `map` shouldn't have side effects