# why do two seemingly identical hashmaps have different behavior when serialized by gson?

Tags: java, hashmap, gson

input:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final String key = "some key";
    final String value = "some value";

    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>(){{put(key, value);}};
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(map1) + " " + map1.get(key));

    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
    map2.put(key, value);
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(map2) + " " + map2.get(key));
}
```

output:

```
null some value
{"some key":"some value"} some value

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Don't abuse ["double brace initialization"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization)...

Comment: also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For `map1`, you have created an anonymous subclass.  Assuming your class that contains `main()` is called `ExampleClass`, then:

```
System.out.println(map1.getClass().getName())
```

prints out:

```
ExampleClass$1
```

Whereas printing the class for `map2` yields:

```
java.util.HashMap
```

As to the exact reason that Gson doesn't serialise it - Gson uses the classname to lookup a converter.  If you instead serialise it using:

```
System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(map1, HashMap.class));
```

... it works as expected.

Comment: [Relevant documentation](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson-java.lang.Object-).