# Alternative to static blocks without unused variable

Tags: java, static-block, unused-variables

As an [alternative to static blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), Oracle docs are suggesting to call a method(s) and the example is using a variable assignment:

> ```
> public static varType myVar = initializeClassVariable();
> ```
>
> The advantage of private static methods is that they can be reused later if you need to reinitialize the class variable.

But if I don't need (and want to avoid unused) extra variable and also return statement in my static block, what is a better way to call static code?

Calling a static method in the constructor is wrong design for executing static code once (constructor can be `private` for utility class) for static block

```
public MyClass() {
     MyClass.initializeClassVariable();
}
```

So is the only improvement is reducing variable access level to private ?

```
 private static varType myVar = initializeClassVariable();
```

Or a better approach is to keep static block and add the method there?

```
static {
    initializeClassVariable();
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"I don't need (and want to avoid unused) extra variable"*? What **extra** variable are you talking about? Isn't the point of the static code to initialize a static field, i.e. the field is there either way?

Comment: @Andreas I don't need `myVar`, it's just defined for executing static code

Comment: Then what does the static code do, if not initializing static fields? The "alternative to static blocks" is about an alternate way of initializing static fields.

Comment: If you use a static block, you don't call the method again through there. You run the code that would have been in the method there as a one-time operation.

Comment: If the static block is not initializing a static field, or is complex logic initializing multiple static fields at the same time, then the "alternative" is not appropriate. The documentation simply mentions that there *is* an alternative, not that it is always applicable, or that you must use it.

Comment: @Andreas I can update several static variables which may not be in class

Comment: Then the alternative is not appropriate. But why is the static code updating static fields in another class? Shouldn't the code be in the other class then?

Comment: @Andreas static fields can be public and you may enter similar logic to update them in separate class

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should. But that's beside the point. The "alternative" is specifically for initializing a single static field in your own class. If that's not what you're doing, then the "alternative" is not appropriate.

Comment: @Andreas Consider also several blocks put different objects to map. I can't assign map more than once

Comment: Then combine the blocks. You never *have to* use more than one static block, though it can help with code readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "alternative to static blocks" is about initializing a single static field.

Example:

```
class A {
    static Map<String, Integer> romans;
    static {
        romans = new HashMap<>();
        romans.put("I", 1);
        romans.put("V", 5);
        romans.put("X", 10);
    }
}
```

Alternative:

```
class A {
    static Map<String, Integer> romans = initRomans();

    private static Map<String, Integer> initRomans() {
        Map<String, Integer> r = new HashMap<>();
        r.put("I", 1);
        r.put("V", 5);
        r.put("X", 10);
        return r;
    }
}
```

As the article says, with this code you can reset the static field.

```
    public static void resetRomans() {
        romans = initRomans();
    }
```

---

If your code does something else, then the "alternative" isn't applicable, and you write the code in a static initializer block.

```
class A {
    static {
        Manager.register(A.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another alternative is an anonymous initialization block

Comment: @faris Yeah, but that's generally a bad idea, see [Efficiency of Java “Double Brace Initialization”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/924285/5221149) It might seems cool, but creating an entire class just to initialize the field, is overkill.