# Java Double Brace Initialization causes IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I just try to create a CRUD Web Application with Spring Boot and I found that there is a problem with using Java Double Brace Initialization in the framework.

```js
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown entity: com.example.service.impl.FileImageServiceImpl$1; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity:
```

I have the `@Entity` class:

```js
@Entity
public class RandomEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
//Getter and Setter
}
```

A `@RestController`

```js
@RestController
public class RandomController{

    @Autowired
    private RandomRepository  randomRepository;

    @GetMapping("/create")
    public String create(){
        RandomEntity rdEntity = new RandomEntity(){{
                setName("Bla Bla");
            }};
        return randomRepository.save();
    }
}
```

Here is the repository

```js
   public interface RandomRepository extends CrudRepository<RandomEntity, Long> {
    }
```

But when I change Java Double Brace Initialization to Normal Initialization, the Application run properly.

Do you know why is that?
Thank you so much!

Comment: just try   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It may look like a nifty shortcut that just calls the constructor of your class followed by some initialization methods on the created instance, but what the so-called [double-brace initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization?rq=1) really does is *create a subclass* of your Entity class. Hibernate will no longer know how to deal with that.

So try to avoid it. It has a lot of overhead and gotchas just to save you a few keystrokes.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I have enough point to say thanks. I have a question, How do you know that?

Answer (score 2):

I just want to complete the answer of [@Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52984268/5558072), If you want a clean code use **Builder design pattern**, now you can implement this Design easily via [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) library, so you can Just annotate your Entity like so :

```
@Entity
@Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
class RandomEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

So there are really some cool annotations, for example `@Getter` and `@Setter` to avoid all that getters and setters, `@Builder(toBuilder = true)` to work with builder design so your controller can look like :

```
@GetMapping("/create")
public RandomEntity create() {

    // Create your Object via Builder design
    RandomEntity rdEntity = RandomEntity.builder()
            .name("Bla Bla")
            .build();

    // Note also here save should take your Object and return RandomEntity not a String
    return randomRepository.save(rdEntity);
}
```