# Java Initialize List, according to another Size

Tags: java, list, java-8, static-initialization

I want to do something Initialize ArrayList with not null items, depending on its size from another variable.

```
private static final int SIZE_LIST_GROUP_MAP = 10;
public static final List<Map<String, String>> LIST_GROUP_MAP = new ArrayList<>() {  
  for(int i=0; i < SIZE_LIST_GROUP_MAP; i++)
  {
    add(new HashMap<>());  
  }  
};
```

Is it possible to do something like that before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are open to using a third-party library, this should work with [Eclipse Collections](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections):

```
public static final List<Map<String, String>> LIST_GROUP_MAP = 
    Lists.mutable.withNValues(SIZE_LIST_GROUP_MAP, HashMap::new);
```

Considering you are storing a mutable `List` containing mutable `Maps` in a static variable, you might want to consider using either a synchronized `List` with synchronized or `ConcurrentMap`s instead. The following code will give you a synchronized `List` containing a fixed set of instances of `ConcurrentMap`.

```
public static final List<Map<String, String>> LIST_GROUP_MAP = 
    Lists.mutable.<Map<String, String>>withNValues(
            SIZE_LIST_GROUP_MAP,
            ConcurrentHashMap::new).asSynchronized()
```

Eclipse Collections also has support for `MultiReaderList`s.

```
public static final List<Map<String, String>> LIST_GROUP_MAP = 
    Lists.multiReader.withNValues(SIZE_LIST_GROUP_MAP, ConcurrentHashMap::new)
```

Finally, if the static `List` will never change in size, then you can make it immutable as follows:

```
public static final ImmutableList<Map<String, String>> LIST_GROUP_MAP =
        Lists.mutable.<Map<String, String>>withNValues(
                SIZE_LIST_GROUP_MAP,
                ConcurrentHashMap::new).toImmutable();
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with double braces, but you end up with a subclass of ArrayList:

```
private static final int SIZE_LIST_GROUP_MAP = 10;
public static final List<Map<String, String>> LIST_GROUP_MAP = new ArrayList<>() {{
    for(int i=0; i < SIZE_LIST_GROUP_MAP; i++)
    {
      add(new HashMap<>());  
    }
}};
```

Check this answer for more details: [Efficiency of Java "Double Brace Initialization"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization)