# Java initialize map with keys from set

Tags: java

In java, can you initialize a new map's keyset based on the values of an existing set?

Something like:

```
Set<String> setOfStrings = getSetFromSomeOtherFuntion();

Map<String, Boolean> map = new Hashmap<>(setOfStrings);
```

If that's possible, then I would presume the value for each entry in the map is null, which is ok, but even better would be if a default value could be set (for example, false if it's Boolean).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Map<K, V> map = new HashMap<>();

setOfStrings.forEach(e -> map.put(e, false));
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use stream with `Collectors.toMap` like so:

```
Map<String, Boolean> map = setOfStrings.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> false));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do it in the constructor, you could do something like this:

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
set.add("Key1");
set.add("Key2");
set.add("Key3");

Map<String, Boolean> map = new HashMap<String, Boolean>() {
    {
        set.forEach(str -> put(str, false));
    }
};

System.out.println(map);
```

Output:

```
{Key2=false, Key1=false, Key3=false}
```

However, this method is a little dirty and honestly unnecessary. You might want to see [Efficiency of Java "Double Brace Initialization"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/924285/5645656)