# Adding integer values to a set in Java

Tags: java

I'm new to using sets in Java, I understand the typical code for adding values to a set is:

```
Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

//then use add method
intSet.add(4);
intSet.add(7);
intSet.add(12);
```

But my question is how can I add multiple values at once, and is it possible to declare the set with its values within the `HashSet<Integer>();` line?
Thanks y'all!

Comment: For an immutable `Set` you use [Set.of(…)](https://www.concretepage.com/java/java-9/java-set-of-example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Answer by Elliott Frisch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69200253/642706) is correct for modifiable sets.

## Unmodifiable sets

You asked:

> is it possible to declare the set with its values within the HashSet(); line?

Yes.

For [unmodifiable sets](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#unmodifiable) in [Java 9+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_9), use [`Set.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#of(E,E,E)).

```
Set< Integer > integers = Set.of( 4 , 7 , 12 ) ;
```

You asked:

> how can I add multiple values at once

You can use `Set.of` as convenient syntax for adding to an existing set. Call [`Set#addAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)).

```
Set< Integer > integers = new HashSet<>() ;
integers.addAll( Set.of( 4 , 7 , 12 ) ) ;
```

That use of `Set.of( 4 , 7 , 12 )` is a modern alternative to [`Arrays.asList( 4 , 7 , 12 )`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) seen in other Answers on this page.

When you are done modifying a set, you may wish to convert it into an unmodifiable set. For example, this approach is usually wise when handing off a set between methods. In [Java 10+](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_10), call [`Set#copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)).

```
Set< Integer > integersUnmodifiable = Set.copyOf( integers ) ;
```

See similar [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/VtRrj2).

Answer (score 3):

You can pass them as part of another `Collection` to the constructor (or use `addAll`). Like,

```
Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(4, 7, 12));
```

or if you need to add multiple lists like

```
Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>();
intSet.addAll(Arrays.asList(4, 7, 12));
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if you had the numbers in another collection, you could add them all at once.

[Documentation link.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-)

But then the question is whether or not it's worth making the other collection in order to use it to make this collection.  If you're making an array from the numbers, and using that to make an ArrayList, and using that to populate the HashMap, it's starting to seem a little indirect for my taste.

It rather depends on the situation. Is "adding 3 constant numbers" a likely scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Initializing with values:

```
  Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6));
```

Adding multiple values:

```
Collections.addAll(set1, 1,2,3,4,5,6);
```

[reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/initialize-hashset-in-java) - Ankith Reddy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Collection of Integers, as the constructor of HashSet accommodates for this:

```
Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2,7,12));
```

To check your code:

```
for(Integer i: intSet){
  System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Output:

```
2 7 12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use double braces initialization like

```
    Set<Integer> intSet = new HashSet<>() {{
    add(4);
    add(7);
    add(12);
}};
```

Comment: this is [wrong idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924285/efficiency-of-java-double-brace-initialization) in most cases

Comment: I understand that it is discouraged to use double braces initialization but it is also a way to add values to Set or List.

Comment: then you should mention it in your answer. Not everybody is aware of it

Comment: True, will keep in mind