# Java Stream: Concat a string out of a map with lists

Tags: java, java-stream

I try to build a string out of all elements of a list that is an element of a map.

```
Map <String, List <String>> map = new HashMap <String, List <String>> ();
map.put ("A", new ArrayList <String> () {{ add ("a"); add ("b"); add ("c"); }});
map.put ("N", new ArrayList <String> () {{ add ("1"); add ("2"); add ("3"); }});
    

String str = map.entrySet ().stream ()
        .filter (x -> x.getKey ().equals ("A"))         // list of map-entry "A"
        .map (x -> x.getValue ().stream ())             // every list-element
        .collect (Collectors.joining ());               // join to str
```

I try to get "abc" inside of str.

Instead I get an error of the compiler ;-)

Compiler-error:

```
The method collect(Collector<? super Stream,A,R>) in the type Stream<Stream> is not applicable for the arguments (Collector<CharSequence,capture#1-of ?,String>)
```

I am not very good with stream-expressions. Where is the problem?

Comment: Why don't you do `String str = String.join("", map.get("A"));`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. You need to use [Stream.flatMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-), not `Stream.map()`, for the mapping operation.

> Returns a stream consisting of the results of replacing each element of this stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element.

2. The map declaration is missing the type of the list

```
Map<String, List> map = ...
```

should be:

```
Map <String, List<String>> map = ...;
```

Without it the compiler won't be able to infer the type of the elements and `Collectors.joining()` can only be used on `CharSequence` - strings, etc.

Comment: I added the type (also in my questiong) - did not help.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the flatMap - its working with it!

Comment: @chris01 there’s still no sense in streaming over an entire map, to perform a linear search for a key, when every `Map` has an efficient `get` method precisely for the purpose of getting the value for a key. So, `String str = String.join("", map.get("A"));` does the entire job. And [don’t use the double brace initialization anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27521612/2711488)