# What's the best way to get console-input in Java?

Tags: java

Getting output with Java is pretty easy as you can make use of `System.out.print` and the like.

Input, on the other hand, seems a little different. Some people recommend [java.util.Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) while others recommend [java.io.BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), and I'm sure there's plenty of other recommendations. The two methods above are most regularly-used.

Neither seem to present very nice options (in my opinion). So, is there any better way to get input from a console window in Java? And if there isn't, which should I choose?

Comment: [Have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/930073/593709)

Comment: Take a look at [JLine](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jline/). It's a command shell-like interface with command history, TAB completion etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, The scanner class is quite helpful. 
For example with BufferedReader, you have to read a line at a time and parse it for the values.
But in the scanner you get integers with nextInt() method etc.

Answer (score 6):

I feel Scanner is helpful in two aspects,

```
1) you can get input from command prompt and infuture if you want to change to file system, it will be quick

2) While reading integer inputs you don't need to parse
```

. I prefer Scanner.

Answer (score 2):

Scanner is handy, but it is  slower than BufferedReader.

Answer (score 2):

1. For console input you can use `System.console()`, which is available in/after JAVA 1.6

   it has options for `readPassword()` (will not show entered character on console as well do not cache it) and `readLine()`.

   ```
   String name = System.console().readLine(); //using java.io.*
   ```
2. Scanner is easiest and good option for less inputs but it's a bit slower than other options like `console()` and `bufferedReader()` when you have so many inputs to handle.

   ```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // using java.util.Scanner;
   String s = in.nextLine();            // for reading string
   int a = in.nextInt();                // for reading int
   float b = in.nextFloat();            // for reading float
   ```
3. I personally like `bufferedReader()` as it will work with earlier versions and non-interactive environments as well plus is faster.

   ```
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));       // using java.io.*
   String name = reader.readLine(); // it reads everything into string
   ```

***p.s:** The `System.console()` method does not work in non-interactive environments (i.e. an IDE).*

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using console if you are using Java 1.6 or latest.

It's simple one liner.

```
String str = System.console().readLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

BufferedReader is quite complex and a bit lengthy to use but it must faster than scanner, 
if you want to take input for competitive coding purpose ,must use BufferedReader. Also there are many way you can check here.https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/fast-io-in-java-in-competitive-programming/

Answer (score 1):

i think scanner is a bit slow, but scanner is better
the problem in scanner is that its difficult to take string input after int input because the nextint doesnt read newline or something
but you can parse it to int or long after taking input as string in nextline()
that way you dont have to worry about the cursor
int a=Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());